# How do I change the computer name?

Tags: hostname

When I connect to my server (ubuntu server 10.10), I get this:

```
name@server-name.belkin ~>
```

How can I remove ".belkin"?

Comment: Try editing /etc/ hosts. gksudo gedit /etc/hosts and replace server-name.belkin by whatever name you desire.

Comment: Do you want to change the actual server name, or just the way it's displayed in the prompt?

Comment: Voting to reopen, because this is a superset (allows restart).

Comment: how does *this* question get closed in favor of one asked ***over a year*** later?

Comment: @warren the current consensus is to close by "quality": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newbie Google keywords on the title.

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 454, accepted):

You need to edit the computer name in two files:

```
/etc/hostname
```

and

```
/etc/hosts
```

These will both need administrative access, so run

```
gksu gedit /path/to/file
```

Replace any instances of the existing computer name with your new one. When complete run

```
sudo service hostname start
```

The name will also be changed if you restart your computer.

See also:

- [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart)

Comment: After that, just `sudo service hostname restart` and the hostname has been changed without rebooting.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 there is no service 'hostname'. What can I do there to avoid reboot.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath `status --system hostname` tells me that the service exists. So, `sudo service hostname restart` or `sudo restart hostname` should work. You probably ran `service hostname status` and it didn't find it. Read [this](http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.pt/2013/04/upstart-user-sessions-in-ubuntu-raring.html) to learn why.

Comment: @BrunoNova Neither of them works.

Comment: `sudo service hostname restart` doesn't work on default install of ubuntu server 14.04 on AWS. I had to do full server restart

Comment: That's strange. I used those commands after changing the hostname in two 14.04 and 14.10 VMs (Desktop version) and it worked. But I probably should have said `sudo service hostname start` (instead of *restart*), since `status --system hostname` returns `hostname stop/waiting`. Also, the current terminal didn't show the new hostname, I had to open a new terminal or shell to see it.

Comment: On 14.04, I simply ran `sudo hostname`, and that did the trick. I didn't notice any immediate change, but when I opened a new terminal, I saw my hostname had indeed changed.

Comment: `sudo hostname new-host-name` worked for me on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: On 15.10, `sudo service hostname restart` fails with `Failed to restart hostname.service: Unit hostname.service is masked.`

Comment: @Lekhnath note: this only works until the next reboot.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 you also have to edit `/etc/hosts` and replace the old hostname with the new one, so that error goes away.

Comment: What does it take to get the change propagated to the DNS server of my home router?

Comment: I see in /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1 localhost - where is the old hostname ?

Comment: What if `/etc/hosts` does not contain the machine name?

Comment: @ThomasWard I did just that and the error doesn't go away.

Comment: What to write in `/etc/hosts`? Why nobody says this explicitly?!

Comment: @Dims, it says in the answer *Replace any instances of the existing computer name with your new one.*

Comment: @richzilla there are no instances of existing computer name in `hosts` by deafult

Comment: "Unable to resolve host" when trying `sudo service hostname start` and `sudo hostname`. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @Fabián Make sure `/etc/hosts` was changed.

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 207):

**`hostnamectl set-hostname` on 13.10+ desktop**

This is the best way if you have systemd (13.10 onwards) and if cloud-init is not active (see below):

```
hostnamectl set-hostname 'new-hostname'
```

It:

- does not require rebooting
- persists after reboots

More info at: https://askubuntu.com/a/516898/52975

**18.04 onwards: cloud-init**

18.04 Introduced [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) which can control setting of the hostname so `hostnamectl` changes it won't stick after a reboot if cloud-init is installed. TODO: how to check if it is installed, is it installed by default on the desktop image or just server?

If you want `hostnamectl` changes to stay after a reboot, then you'll need to edit the [cloud-init config files](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), disable cloud-init's [hostname set/update module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#update-hostname):

```
sudo sed -i 's/preserve_hostname: false/preserve_hostname: true/' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
```

or disable cloud-init entirely:

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

See also: [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart/1047635#1047635)

Comment: Doesn't change /etc/hosts in 14.04

Comment: @SandeepDatta thanks for feedback. Were you expecting that to be changed? I'm not sure how it works, but when I tested it the effect was permanent after reboot.

Comment: works perfectly in ubuntu 16.04... thanks a lot

Comment: Confirmed to work correctly in 16.10 also

Comment: I had to add my new-hostname into /etc/hosts else using sudo would cause some error "sudo: unable to resolve host xxxxx"

Comment: Worked for me. Later on I had some errors of "sudo: uanble to resolve host...". After reading here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-user I checked `/etc/hosts` and it had the old hostname. After I changed `/etc/hosts` to the current hostname, everything is working.

Comment: On an Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 with systemd 229 this return "Could not set property: Connection timed out". [Here systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6563) say look downstream, maybe [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1635382) (also [on Red Hat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1482800)).

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Comment: For posterity: [How to change hostname on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-hostname-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Comment: Working also with Ubuntu 20 LTS as desktop, and only using `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname myNewName`. After new terminal and after boot (!), the` myNewName`, no problem.

Comment: Works like a charm in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Worked perfectly in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 72):

It's quite easy:

1. Edit `/etc/hostname`, make the name change, save the file.
2. You should also make the same changes in `/etc/hosts` file
3. Run `sudo service hostname start`

As long as you have no application settings depending on the 'old' hostname, you should be ok ;-)

Comment: WARNING: If you do this  without changing /etc/hosts accordingly you will be unable to use sudo because your hostname will fail to lookup

Comment: You're right regarding editing the /etc/hosts, i forgot about it (just added it to my answer), though sudo seems to be working fine for me without changing it (i've restarted the machine and it still works)

Comment: I don't have any reference to my hostname (new or old) in `/etc/hosts`, only localhost and some IPv6 rules.

Comment: networkmanager adds it, at least that happens in my machine.

Comment: I have xubuntu 10.10 and when did the second step, it told me to run `sudo service hostname restart`.

Comment: It's ok, you can do that as `hostname` is now a service managed from `upstart`. It'll do exactly the same thing,restart the service.

Comment: Note: this will not work for ubuntu 14.x, as `hostname` is no longer in `init.d`

Comment: If you ever find you can't restart `hostname` simply reboot the machine with `sudo reboot`.

Comment: `sudo: /etc/init.d/hostname: command not found`

Comment: What do you mean "same changes" in /etc/hosts? This file has completely different format!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: `Failed to start hostname.service: Unit hostname.service is masked.`

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 26):

It is safe to do, you just need to be sure you edit both the system hostname configuration file (/etc/hostname) and the hostname name resolution file (/etc/hosts).
From a terminal execute the following:

```
sudo -s
editor /etc/hostname
editor /etc/hosts
shutdown -ry now
```

Comment: You can avoid shutdown with `sudo service hostname restart`.

Comment: @Wtower Doesn't work with 14.04. :(

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to editing /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname, various services might have issues with the change as well.  Mysql and postfix are installed by default in ubuntu.  A broken postfix won't affect most ubuntu users, since it's a background email server that isn't used by much.

Postfix:

```
sudo editor /etc/postfix/main.cf
sudo service postfix restart
```

The default config for mysql doesn't use hostname, so it will work fine as-is.  If you have customized it, edit the files in /etc/mysql/ and restart the service.

You may also want to edit /etc/motd  (message of the day), which is shown on virtual terminals and remote logins.  That one won't harm anything though.

Other services that you may have installed that would need fixing are apache, bind9, etc.  In each case, find and edit the hostname in their config and restart the service.

Answer (score 15):

The *host name* uniquely identifies your computer on the local network (and possibly on the Internet as well) so it's not a good idea to change it unless you know what you are doing.

But you can change the shell prompt not to display the `.belkin` (domain name part):

```
export PS1='\u@\h \w> '
```

See the [bash man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/bash) and specifically the [section on prompting](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc26) for more information.

Answer (score 15):

### **Another better and safe way to rename hostname**

**Install ailurus**

- Add the PPA and update your repository

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ailurus && sudo apt-get update`
- Install ailurus

  `sudo apt-get install ailurus`
- After installation it will be found under **Applications>>System Tools>>Ailurus**
  [image]

Comment: Why is this getting negative votes?  Should be better to configure something with a dedicated tool than muck around on the command line and break things in the process.

Comment: Installing such a big software just to change a hostname is a bit of an overkill

Comment: I agree that this is overkill -- in particular because the software not available in the repositories but has to be installed from a PPA...

Comment: @karthick87 perhaps mention in your answer that this is a large piece of software (with other configuration options)? - personally I agree with endolith that a tool with a single, simple change point is better than lots of command line operations (I use Ubuntu Tweak, also currently available from a PPA)

Comment: I think that you can break a lot more things (and more easily) using this tool, than just replacing a word in a couple of files. It exposed too many things to you.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `hostname` command to change your hostname

```
sudo hostname newname
```

However, this does not edit your hosts file, which you must do so as to make sure that your computer recognizes itself

```
gksudo /etc/hosts
```

And add a new entry for your hostname pointing to 127.0.0.1

```
127.0.0.1 oldname newname
```

You could remove the old entry as well, but I prefer to keep it there.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to play with a text editor, [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) (grab the deb from their website) has that as one of the little things you can play with (along with lots of other little tweaks that you might want to make but don't really want to play around with the terminal and the files themselves).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason why Ubuntu Tweak is not in the software repos?

Comment: They never got around to adding it/haven't been accepted. You can add their repo to your list either right after starting tweak or through the terminal/repo list.

Comment: You can also add Ubuntu Tweak as a PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa` then `sudo apt-get update` then 
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Comment: note that since ~13.04 Ubuntu Tweak no longer provides this option

Answer (score 7):

The following command change the hostname on the fly but to make it permanent, you have to edit `/etc/hostname`:

```
echo 'new_hostname' > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

Open a new terminal session and you'll see it right away.

With `systemd` in place, the proper way to do it is

```
hostnamectl set-hostname "new_name"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a GUI assisted process install Ubuntu-Tweak.  Among other uses of this app is the ability to change computer name through tab "Computer-Details" -> "Hostname"

Answer (score 4):

SystemSettings -> Details -> Overwiev (default opened in U16.04) - Device Name.

but additionally you must change name in /etc/hosts. Ubuntu BUG()?

Comment: I think this a rather nice way to change the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and

```
sudo sed -i '1s/.*/desired-name/g' /etc/hostname

# you need restart to effect with...

sudo shutdown -r 0
```

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason all answers are about changing the hostname. However the goal of just showing the first part of the hostname can be achieved in other way.

You just need to find a place in your `.bashrc` file where the `PS1` is set and replace `\H` with `\h`.

[man bash - prompting](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/bash.1.html#prompting)