# Safe way to rename my computer/hostname?

Tags: configuration, hostname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the computer name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name)

I'd like to rename my computer. What's the recommended way to do this? Is there anything likely to break after I rename it?

Comment: Should this be merged with http://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/rename-computer-name ?