# If I rename my computer, will it lead to problems with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, hostname

If I rename my computer by editing the `/etc/hostname` file as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16442/safe-way-to-rename-my-computer-hostname), will I get some synchronization problems with Ubuntu One, which knows my machine as a different name ?

Can I have any other problem I don't think of yet ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the only problem will be that it will be still listed with the old name. If that inconsistency bothers you you can delete the token and re-sign in to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull when changing the hostname, From the IRC #ubuntu channel factoid i quote:

Use hostname  to set the hostname, 
 or to do it permanently: edit /etc/hosts to include BOTH the old
 and new hostname and then change /etc/hostname to the new one.

WARNING! Make sure that your current hostname and
 /etc/hosts match, otherwise sudo may not work properly.

I have never had an issue with ubuntu one after changeing hostnames.