# Error message "sudo: unable to resolve host (none)"

Tags: sudo, error-handling

When I run `sudo` the terminal is stuck for a few seconds and then outputs an error message. My terminal looks like this:

```
ubuntu@(none):~$ sudo true
sudo: unable to resolve host (none)
```

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Please post the contents of `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I recommend against closing this question as *too localized*. There are many users who may mistakenly think they've put one name in their `hosts` file but put in a different name instead, especially since on many networks, computers are similarly named. This question (and answer) would show up when someone searches with that problem, and the answer would prompt them to check for such discrepancies, even though the exact misspelling would be different.

Comment: make sure your `hostname` same with `hosts`. e.g. the hostname is **ubuntu-pc** and hosts is **ubuntu-pc** must be same.

Comment: I ran into this today.  The problem was that what I had in hostname wasn't in /etc/hosts.  To wit: $ hostname  => 'mybox'  $ grep 'mybox' /etc/hosts  => 192.168.1.2  mybox.example.com.  I needed to add 'mybox' after my domain name in /etc/hosts => 192.168.1.2 mybox.example.com mybox

Comment: I can't post an answer because this question is protected and I don't have enough reputation here. In my case, I solved the problem by restarting network-manager: `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`. However, I'm wondering why in the first place `sudo` wastes time waiting for network-related stuff. Shouldn't `sudo` work without problems when network is not available?

Comment: Why does the question have `<USER>` at the end? This contradicts the actual output shown in the body of the question as `(none)`  Suggestion for improvement: remove `<USER>` from title and/or replace it with `(none)`

Comment: @arielf You can improve questions on here. It was changed by another user. I don't know either. :P

Answer (score 1299, accepted):

Two things to check (assuming your machine is called `my-machine`, you can change this as appropriate):

1. That the `/etc/hostname` file contains just the name of the machine.
2. That `/etc/hosts` has an entry for `localhost`. It should have something like:

   ```
    127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost
    127.0.1.1    my-machine
   ```

If either of these files aren't correct (since you can't sudo), you may have to reboot the machine into recovery mode and make the modifications, then reboot to your usual environment.

Comment: The hostname will not change until you reboot. If you wish to change it without rebooting the machine then follow the above steps and after that run:- "sudo hostname my-machine" to see if this has worked run "sudo hostname" It will show your machine's host name. This method maybe used as a temporary method to change hostname also. after a restart, the value from the /etc/hostname file is used.

Comment: Note: since you can't sudo to begin with, it is difficult to edit those files. My solution was I was somehow able to sudo visudo and change `#%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` to `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` , then reboot, and sudo su -, edit those files, set/correct hostname, reboot again, and everything worked.

Comment: I'm using Linux Subsystem in Windows and I faced this problem. After following your answer, It has been resolved.

Comment: @amarVashishth can you list the steps taken? I am facing the same problem. I tried what the answer tells to do but failed

Comment: @MeetTaraviya I followed same steps as he told. It worked for me.

Comment: @amarVashishth "reboot the machine into recovery mode" . Does that mean the actual pc or just the linux subsystem?

Comment: doesn't work, now I can't TV into my server

Comment: you may also need to add `::1 localhost` to `/etc/hosts` (this is the IPv6 version of 127.0.0.1, aka the loopback address)

Comment: It worked for me with `sudo gedit /etc/hosts`, then changing and saving the file.

Comment: @MeetTaraviya I just skipped the reboot step. For WSL (Windows Linux Subsystem) it is enough to just edit `/etc/hosts`. Note that you have to replace `my-machine` with the host name from the error message on your computer.

Comment: Why does your example  have `127.0.0.1 localhost` but `127.0.1.1 my-machine`?

Comment: in my case the reason was that `hostnamectl set-hostname ...` change `/etc/hostname` **but no `/etc/hosts`**.

Comment: good find. Now I wonder if a bug should be reported against gnome-settings, because that's where I changed by hostname after moving disks...

Comment: Do you really, really use 127.0.1.1  and not 127.0.0.1 for the new hostname? Just asking because the second highest rated answer only uses 127.0.0.1, and 127.0.1.1 doesn't work for me.

Comment: @crobar: yep, that's what I have; 127.0.0.1 for localhost, and 127.0.1.1 for the hostname.

Comment: @JeremyKerr thanks, actually it wasn't working for me because of a setting in `nsswitch.conf` i can confirm it does work for me now with 127.0.1.1

Comment: edit the /etc/hostname file and make sure it has only the name provided at cat hostname. Then make sure this name is the same even in /etc/hosts. It worked for me just fine!

Comment: This question does not define what "my-machine" means or how to even get that value. Rated down till resolved. My assumption is /etc/hostname will output "my-machine", but I cannot be certain.

Answer (score 248):

[Edit](https://askubuntu.com/q/92379/6969) `/etc/hosts` and append your new hostname to the 127.0.0.1 line (or create a new line if you prefer that).

Mine looks like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain penguin

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Replace `penguin` in the above example by your new hostname as stated in the `/etc/hostname` file.

Comment: How can he edit the /etc/hosts file if he can't sudo? Unless he created a rood account with a password (bad idea)

Comment: @Dennis You can still execute `sudo` even if that message is displayed. IIRC you still have to enter your password at each invocation though. If this does not work, you can reboot into the recovery console and apply the changes. A root account with password is discouraged.

Comment: helpful answer.

Comment: as a debian user, there is no gksudo or gksu, i had to resort to using sed: **step 1.** run `touch myscript` **step 2.** edit "myscript" (you can do this without sudo most of the time) and insert `sed -i 's/127.0.0.1 localhost/127.0.0.1 localhost NEWHOSTHERE/' /etc/hosts` **step 3.** `sudo bash myscript`. Please note the tabs are there on purpose because it searches for `127.0.0.1 localhost` to be replaced with `127.0.0.1 localhost NEWHOSTHERE`.

Answer (score 91):

Add your hostname to `/etc/hosts` like so:

```
echo $(hostname -I | cut -d\  -f1) $(hostname) | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: It's clever, but I don't think it tends to be a good idea to automate something like this.

Comment: This does an append of the hostname to the hosts file. There is an inherent assumption that there is nothing in between the loopback ip the mapping to localhost and end of file, but there is now some IPv6 stuff between this line and end of file, in which case this solution does not really end up giving you what you would want. A related comment: Editing this or other files requires use of sudo and it is sudo that we are trying to fix. We still need to be able to run sudo. In this case sudo -h hostname can be used to first change permissions on the files or gain the elevation to edit them.

Comment: this fails because I can't "sudo tee.."
but this did the trick: 

`echo $(hostname -I | cut -d\  -f1) $(hostname) | sudo -h 127.0.0.1 tee -a /etc/hosts `

Comment: working completely fine

Answer (score 38):

**Note, this is an answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/177368/70786) which has been merged with this one.**

Your hostname (`dave00-G31M-ES2L`) is not represented in `/etc/hosts`. Add an `L` to this line:

```
127.0.1.1   dave00-G31M-ES2
```

So it becomes:

```
127.0.1.1   dave00-G31M-ES2L
```

In order to accomplish this, open a console (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

Add the letter `L` as mentioned, save and exit.

Comment: Remember! Use `sudoedit` (or `sudo -e`). To specify preferred editor, use the `EDITOR` environment variable (eg. `export EDITOR=vim`) as it creates an offline copy for editing and then cleanly overwrites after editing.

Comment: And there is another one here who suggest `sudo` when there is no longer `sudo`. `sudo` doesn't work, sir. `sudo: unable to resolve host ...`

Comment: @Green: No `sudo`? The error message you mention comes from the `sudo` command. Perhaps you meant something different?

Comment: @Green `sudo` works just fine. It just can't store any state (i.e. as Lekensteyn said elsewhere you have to enter your password every time).

Comment: If you have this issue on W10's Bash and came to this question from google, this is the answer that worked for me. I changed the 127.0.0.1 to look like "127.0.0.1 localhost DESKTOP-SLQK4CV" (by doing "sudo vim /etc/hosts" (quick tip for vim newbies: press i before typing to switch to insert mode, press esc to exit that, write ":wq" to save and exit or ":q!" to exit without saving), in my case sudo worked but just said that it can't connect to DESKTOP-SLQK4CV) and it started worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I had this issue when I was using ubuntu on a VPS. I solved it editing /etc/hosts file.

run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and then add:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu
```

I hope that will solve your issue :)

PS: Remember to reboot your computer!

Comment: Also, see if your device name (printed on the Terminal title bar after the @ sign) matches the name on the second line of the `hosts` file ("ubuntu" in Luca's example). The first line may also be just "localhost".

Comment: Remember! Use `sudoedit` (or `sudo -e`). To specify preferred editor, use the `EDITOR` environment variable (eg. `export EDITOR=vim`) as it creates an offline copy for editing and then cleanly overwrites after editing.

Comment: Isn't this answer essentially the same as this [older one](https://askubuntu.com/a/119723/116961)?

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue even though the hostname in my /etc/hostname file and /etc/hosts file matched.

My hostname was "staging_1". It turns out that you can't have an underscore in your hostname, which is why I was getting this error. Changing the underscore to a hyphen fixed my problem.

Answer (score 12):

In AWS, go to your vpc and turn on "DNS Hostnames".

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Can you expand a bit on this? It's not abundantly clear what you mean (at least to me)..

Comment: This was the answer that helped me. Amazon AWS changed since the last time I looked at it. VPCs have DNS options, and they need to be turned on before any DNS resolution will work.

Comment: the Enable DNS Hostnames option can be found (for example) in the right-click menu of the vpc entry

Comment: There is no `DNS Hostnames`

Comment: Similar issue occurred on Azure for me when I changed the default DNS servers in the VNet. I fixed it by adding my current hostname to the hosts file using `sudo --host 127.0.0.1 vi /etc/hosts`, as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 10):

The symptom given in the question may correlate strongly with this more specific problem:

```
$ hostname --fqdn
hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

There are different ways that this could be resolved, one of which is to add your hostname as localhost in `/etc/hosts` (as shown in several other answers).  This may be the right thing to do in general, but it isn't the only possible resolution.

A "fully qualified domain name" may be supplied by an external DNS server or similar (if such is available on your network).  In this case, `sudo` will not complain, despite the missing entry in `/etc/hosts`.

---

Note: `sudo` attempts to dereference the hostname, even though it isn't necessarily required, due to optional capabilities in the sudoers file.  See [sudo command trying to search for hostname](https://superuser.com/q/429790).

As long as the delay isn't too long, this error message is typically harmless.

Comment: Somewhat faster: `sudo --host=localhost`

Comment: Upvote for the [sudo command trying to search for hostname](https://superuser.com/a/429890/185665) link

Comment: This is interesting: [Bash hangs in Linux subsystem in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1184971/114579)

Answer (score 10):

Everybody advises to modify `/etc/hosts`. But in some cases this may not be possible (for example inside a docker container). So, I had to find a better way and I came up with this:

```
echo "alias sudo='sudo -h 127.0.0.1'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
```

Aliases don't work in bash scripts, but we can use variables: `sudo='sudo -h 127.0.0.1'`

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this same error message. I think this discussion thread at AWS Developer Forums is a better solution:

**"Go the the VPC management console, select the VPC, click on Actions, select Edit DNS Hostnames and select Yes."**

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=699718

Answer (score 6):

Some terminal emulators will not update prompt with the correct hostname until you close and restart the emulator (lxterminal, I'm talking to you).

I spent 30min fighting with this error after editing my *hostname* and *hosts* files and running `sudo service hostname restart` until I ran `sudo hostname` and saw that the hostname was the new value, even though the prompt was showning the old value.

Comment: The issue isn't the terminal emulators, it's the shells that have cached the value.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was the problem, I changed the `hostname` to `man` because I wanted to know if there are some parameters you can use on `hostname`. Instead it changed my `hostname` to `man` and I always got the same message like you

```
sudo: unable to resolve host (none)
```

after changing the hostname back to `localhost everything worked fine again

```
hostname localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I can't help you much but, since it says "can't resolve host" try running:

```
hostname
```

And see if the output is the hostname of the machine. If not, the problem is the host configuration, not sudo.

Comment: I did that got the hostname of my machine. I also have entry in /etc/hosts. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Did you reboot the machine after changing the hosts file?

Comment: No. Though my IT team said there was issue with lock file as well as gpg key with puppetlabs. Now, it got resolved without restart..

Answer (score 2):

OP wrote:

> It was all in /etc/hostname. On two of our sick servers it looked like
>   this:
>
> ```
> ubuntu@(none):~$ cat /etc/hostname
> linux-web-n ip-10-128-##-##
> ```
>
> While on a server without this issue we had:
>
> ```
> ubuntu@ip-10-128-##-###:~$ cat /etc/hostname
> ip-10-128-##-###
> ```
>
> Removed the `linux-web-n` portion, rebooted and everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

you might be getting an error if your hosts or hostname file contain illegal characters. Only these symbols are permitted:  a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Answer (score 2):

if you can't sudo you CAN log in as root via su.
IE: su root   (in an x-term).
then give the root password when prompted, then you can edit the files with nano.  The root password in 'buntu is the same as the password you would use for sudo.

Comment: The root password in Ubuntu is not the same password for `sudo`. `root` is its own account, which doesn't have a password set by default.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem! I changed my VPS's name through the online admin control panel which did not change the machine name in the hosts file All I did was run:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Then I edited it from this:

```
127.0.1.1 Megabyte Megabyte
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

To this:

```
127.0.1.1 Debian Debian
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

and that fixed my error! Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

In case your problem is that `/etc/hostname` file and `/etc/hosts`, both files have your desired hostname and still your machine is showing the error

> `sudo: unable to resolve host`

Try, forcing the hostname

```
sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

You will probably still get the same error, but try logging out and logging back in. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by editing the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files... on the /etc/hosts file, just edit the top part as shown below.

```
#vi /etc/hosts
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    127.0.1.1   localhost  myhostname




#vi /etc/hostname
    myhostname
```

Comment: `127.0.1.1   localhost  myhostname` or `127.0.1.1    myhostname`?

Comment: How can you edit `/etc/hosts` without `sudo`. `sudo` doesn't work `sudo: unable to resolve host ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vagrant, then login into the guest and run
    `apt-get --no-install-recommends install virtualbox-guest-utils`