# How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?

Tags: permissions, configuration, root

I can't seem to edit and save config files in the root system (eg: `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config`); it just says "permission denied" or the save option is blocked in the text editor.

I'm pretty sure I'm a root user, but how do I make sure? If I am a root user, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Which text editor are you using? If you are a sudoer and know your password, try (in a terminal) either:

- `sudoedit /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config` if you are using a terminal-based editor such as `nano` or are ssh'ing into a server.
- `gedit admin:///etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config` using the [the `admin://` protocol](https://askubuntu.com/a/868882/158442) with GNOME applications such as `gedit` (and others that support GVfs).
- `sudo -H <text editor> /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config` for GUI editors in general.
- In old versions of Ubuntu, `gksudo <text editor here> /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config` could be used to launch GUI editors.

In either case, you'll need to first provide your password when requested.

In Ubuntu 14.04 onwards, `gksudo` is not installed by default. You will have to install the `gksu` package (either from the Software Centre or via `sudo apt-get install gksu`) to get it.

In Ubuntu 17.10, Wayland is default instead of the traditional X server, and running graphical editors as root is difficult. See [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/q/961967/158442) for details.

In Ubuntu 18.04, `gksudo` is not available in the official repositories.

Comment: The save location changes for some reason to var/tmp/filename. Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to use a terminal, you can invoke a GUI program as root thus (this example is for Gedit):

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the Run dialog.
2. Type `gksudo` followed by the executable name of your program (which might be different from the name displayed by the GUI). For example:

   ```
   gksudo gedit
   ```
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 10):

I can't think of a case where root would get `permission denied`.

In 12.04 you can do it like this:  <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and enter `gksudo` in the box that appears like this:

[image: F2 dialogue]

You get a box like this and enter `gedit` and click <kbd>ok</kbd>:

[image: Type gedit in Run dialogue]

Click <kbd>Open</kbd>:

[image: Open tab inside gedit]

Just browse to the file:

[image: open files dialogue]

Done

Warning:  There is a super-user/root for a reason.  It's so that you don't accidentally put something bad or out of structure in something important by mistake.  You should be exceedingly careful that whatever you edit as root is the correct file you mean to edit AND that your syntax is perfect.  If other tools are available for editing, it's recommended to use those. For instance, use the `visudo` [terminal command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) instead of manually editing `/etc/sudoers`.

Some files that could get messed up are easy to recover from.  Others are relatively complicated or you have to use recovery console and a lot of command lines.

Yes the recovery console command line seems a little scarier than even [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal).  Just be careful.

Comment: You might need to update this for 13.04 and newer. Some things relating to gksu/gksudo have changed (not sure if that applies to your answer or not though).

Comment: It's my understanding sudo now magically exports DISPLAY environment variables and gksu/gksudo have gone or are going away.  I haven't checked though.

Comment: `root` can get permission denied if the file has been set immutable using `chattr` or sometimes if the disk is read-only.

Answer (score 6):

You can test if your current shell is running as root a few different ways

```
~/ > whoami
paul
~/ > sudo whoami
root
~/ > id
uid=1000(paul) gid=1000(paul) groups=1000(devs),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),…
~/ > sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) group=0(root)
```

Other answers give good ways to escalate to root privilege, so I won't repeat those.  Assuming you *are* root and you still can't edit the file `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config` - then *very* probably someone or some program has used the `chattr` program to make the file immutable.

From the [chattr manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr):

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` capability can set or clear this attribute.

You can find out by using [`lsattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsattr)

```
lsattr /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config
```

If indeed it's immutable you can turn that off like this:

```
chattr -i /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Ubuntu 17.04** or higher, it is recommended to use the *gvfs admin backend*. Simply add `admin://` to the front of the full filepath you want to open in an app like the *Text Editor* or the *Files apps*.

For instance, to change boot settings, open

```
admin:///etc/default/grub
```

If you are using Ubuntu 17.10 with the default Wayland, `sudo` and `gksu` as mentioned in the older answer here will **not** work.

Answer (score 2):

## Use Your Favourite Text Editor

You can use [`sudo -e`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sudo.8.html) or its alias [`sudoedit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sudo.8.html) with your favourite (graphical!) text editor through the `VISUAL` environment variable<sup>1</sup>:

```
VISUAL=gedit sudo -e /path/to/some-config-file.cfg
```

which is equivalent to

```
VISUAL=gedit sudoedit /path/to/some-config-file.cfg
```

Of course you can use any other editor that you like, e. g. `leafpad`, `kate`, or `subl`.

Some editor offer a command-line option to *always* start a new instance, even if one is currently running. Since `sudoedit` waits for the editor process to terminate to apply changes to the edited file, this may be necessary if you have other instances of the same Editor running:

- For GEdit use `VISUAL='gedit -s'`.
- For Kate use `VISUAL='kate -n'`.

---

### Advantages

- Doesn’t require additional and/or deprecated applications.
- Doesn’t require security policy changes like `pkexec` (for which you’d need to edit files… as super-user, the exact thing this answer is trying to solve).
- Doesn’t require the execution of potentially unsafe applications with elevated privileges.
- Uses the current user’s application configuration but mess with the configuration file access permissions like `sudo -H` etc.
- Doesn’t fall back onto the user application configuration data of the `root` user which may or may not look and behave acceptably.

### Disadvantages

- You need to learn a short new command.

---

<sup>1</sup> `EDITOR` or `SUDO_EDITOR` work too but take less priority or are more specialised respectively. See the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sudo.8.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe back it up using `cp /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config /$HOME/dhcpd.config.backup`
and run `gksu gedit /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config`

Replace `gedit` with the editor of your choice

you will get a prompt like this

[image: password prompt]

Enter your password here.

A new window opens and you can edit your config there.

In case something goes wrong you can restore it from your backup in the home folder.

You get "permission denied" because of how Linux handles permission.

Anything in the `$HOME` folder belongs to the user, whereas almost anything else belongs to root.

The `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file you are trying to access belongs to root, and most files in `/etc/` belong to root by default for security reasons.

You can still edit this file by elevating your permissions.

To do this you have a number of ways:

- use `su` which stands for switch user. Without any attributes to it, it functions as a command to switch to the root account, but you need to enter the password of the user you are switching to, and since root has no password by default on Ubuntu (effectively disabling the root account), this won't work unless you have set a password for root, which is not recommended.
- using `sudo` which elevates your permission for only one command. This is generally used only for command-line apps such as CLI text editors like `vim`,`nano` etc
- using `gksu` which elevates your permission for only one command, but unlike `sudo` is used for graphical programs such as GUI text editors like `gedit` . it uses a graphical prompt to facilitate entering of a password.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo < editor > < filelocation >
```

e.g.:

```
sudo -H gedit etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config
```