# Can not change the files

Tags: permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

I have files kept under the folder /opt/.
When I am trying to edit the files, could not because the permission is denied.

How to give the permission?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` or `gksudo` to act on them as root.
`chown user:group` to change ownership.
`chmod 'permission in octal'` to change permission type for user:group:everyone
`su user` to switch to an appropriate user.

I frequently put things in /opt that belong to multiple users, but are pretty portable and not in repos.  I don't think saying 'use sudo' is necessarily right for '/opt' specific questions.