# Problem upgrading 11.04

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade my ubuntu 11.04 desktop computer, but when I click on the ugrade button:

[image]

I get this error:

I've tryied to change my repositories, but it changes nothing in the error((on the "setting new software channel").
[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is my sources.list:

```
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ailurus/ppa/ubuntu karmic main # disabled on upgrade to karmic
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ailurus/ppa/ubuntu karmic main # disabled on upgrade to karmic

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 9.04 _Jaunty Jackalope_ - Release i386 (20090421.3)]/ jaunty main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted multiverse universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted multiverse universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users. deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted multiverse universe deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
# deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org karmic main # disabled on upgrade to maverick
# deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org karmic main # disabled on upgrade to maverick deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main #Third party developers repository
```

Comment: Remove jaunty repositories from your repository list

Comment: @aking1012 I can't find any mention of jaunty anywhere... Added my source.list do the question

Comment: @aking1012 I know it's a noob question, but how do I open the file (in the gui) with root privilegues? (I can only read the file, not write)

Comment: Updating without a problem as I write this, if you right it as an answer, I'll give you the points.and also THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: No problem.  Glad it worked out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove any `jaunty` related repositories from your sources list or sources list.d/*.
The reason I jump straight for jaunty is that in your screenshot, the archives that are failing have `jau` as the start of the distribution name.

It may be finding `deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-backports main restricted universe multiverse` or there may be something else in your sources.list.d.

You can edit your /etc/sources.list.d with a text editor like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files/121790#121790).  If you're going to edit it make a copy first.  Like that answer says, you need to be very careful editing system configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can ping pt.archive.ubuntu.com, if this does not work ... try modifying your

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

to remove references for "pt" and leave "archive.ubuntu.com". This will effect your download speed for new installs and updates but it may resolve the issue.

Comment: Ping was OK,no problem there...