# What are the standard file permissions for the /etc directory(file)

Tags: virtualbox, permissions, chmod, recovery-mode, etc

I kinda screwed up the /etc directory by running:

```
sudo chmod 417 /etc
```

Leaving me unable to use sudo:

```
sudo: can't open /etc/sudoers: permission denied.
sudo: no valid sudoers sources foundm quitting
```

Ive been trying to fix it via recovery mode but i'm not sure to what mode I should set it.
(I know sudoers is 0440, but this doesnt fix it because /etc is still messed up.)

Oh and for the future,   how do i add lines to files in etc without screwing up the permissions of etc?

Thanks in advance,
Joeri.

P.S. Im running in Virtual box if that makes a difference.

***Edit:***
Booting in recovery and running:

```
root@joeri-VirtualBox:/# chmod 755 etc
chmod: changing permissions of 'etc' : read-only file system
root@joeri-VirtualBox:/# cd etc
root@joeri-VirtualBox:/etc# ls -ld
drw-rw-rwx 139 root root 12288 2012-04-19 16:29
```

Doesnt change the permissions of etc.
Doing the same on a self created folder on the desktop does, so chmod is working,  just not on etc.

Comment: You mean you running ubuntu in Virtual box? Not in WUBI or as a dual boot?

Comment: Yep I am running it in virtual box.  The dual boot had problems with getting into the university network.

Comment: The general approach to editing files owned by `root` is to use either `sudo` or `gksudo`. There are lots of questions whose answers describe how to do that. For an example take a look at [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

`drwxr-xr-x 157 root root 12288 2012-04-19 07:40 /etc`

`sudo chmod 755 /etc`

Hope that helps ...

Comment: Thanks,
but running

     chmod 755 /etc

From recovery didt fix my sudo acces problem.

Comment: Actually running chmod ### /etc in recovery as root doesnt seem to change annything.

:/etc$ ls -ld keeps returning drw-rw-rwx 139 no matter what i place at ###.

Comment: If you're running from the recovery disk, your real disk may be mounted at a different location, perhaps `/target`.  `mount` will show you where it is, then you can chroot `etc` within that.

Comment: In recovery mode you need  probably to  remount the root filesystem with read/write permission `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: Or you could just execute the `fsck` option in the recovery mode menu. After it completes you file system should be remounted as `read/write`.

Answer (score 0):

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh! Can you please provide an explanation on the meaning of this command, and what is actually does?

Comment: pkexec repair permission of sudoers file

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel What Alaa Ali means is: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what your command does with the intention of educating the OP and thousands of future researchers regarding how/when/why it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: @0xF2: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/641754/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: **abhishyam**: could you also explain the *why* of your solution?