# Create a distro with relinux

Tags: installation, ubiquity, relinux

I want to create a distro from ubuntu 12.04(with relinux)

My problems:

- I want to remove and change these parts

[image]

- How to change ubuntu name and logo in Details (system setting-->Details)

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you had set the `SYSNAME` variable (relinux 0.3) or `Name of the OS` (relinux 0.4), it should have worked, but due to a bug either in relinux or ubiquity (not sure which to blame, the issue is kind of complex), it doesn't work.

There are 2 ways of fixing/getting around the issue:

- Using the latest git version of relinux, as this issue is fixed there (Instructions here: https://github.com/MiJyn/relinux/wiki/Installing , follow "Downloading via git", "Installing", then "Running")
- Edit `/etc/lsb-release` yourself

If you want to do the second method, open `/etc/lsb-release` in a text editor **as root** (see: [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)). You should see something similar to this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04"
```

First, backup the file (save it as `/etc/lsb-release.bak`, or save it in your home folder, if you don't want it to appear on the ISO), then edit it to what you want. Here's a reference of the variables:

- `DISTRIB_ID`: Name of the distro
- `DISTRIB_RELEASE`: Current version of the distro installed
- `DISTRIB_CODENAME`: Codename of the version (if you don't have one, just use the version itself, it *should* work fine)
- `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION`: As it says, just a description of the OS. Ubuntu seems to like to use the "NAME VERSION" format, but you can really do whatever you want here.

Notice that you will need to surround it in double quotes (`"`) if you use more than one word (like you can see in `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION`)

Once you're done, save it (as `/etc/lsb-release`), and close. Now you have to tell relinux to not edit `/etc/lsb-release`. In relinux 0.4, make sure `Generate LSB Files` is **not** checked, and in relinux 0.3, make sure `GENERATELSBRELEASE` is set to `N` (i.e. `GENERATELSBRELEASE="N"`).

Once that is done, run relinux, and it should work!