# How do I create a .conf file?

Tags: wireless

On start up I get this message:

```
Support for cores revision ox17 and ox18 disabled by module param allsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
```

I found an answer which stated I needed to create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf`

I don't know how to do this. At the moment it will boot the system without the Network Manager which I can then manually switch on by typing:

```
   gksu service network-manager start
```

Comment: Try `gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: I believe it is suggesting that you add it to boot options, however, let's see if there is a fixable problem with your Broadcom wireless device. Please post: lspci -nn | grep 0280  Is your wireless working? Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: Thank you @chili555 when I put in lspci-nn|grep0280 it says 'command not found' I'm sorry, I am new to all of this. Yes, my wireless is working after I put gksu service network-manager start in the terminal.
I can also connect using Wicd Network Manager. But On Start Up It still says 'Booting System without Network Configuration'

Comment: It is not lspci-nn|grep0280; it is lspci  -nn  |  grep  0280 The spaces are important and required.

Comment: My apologies @chili555, the output from that is:

        `02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)`

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your system in helped by having both Network Manager and Wicd competing for control. I recommend you remove Wicd. Let's create the .conf file. In a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you haven't the text editor gedit. Add a single line:

```
options b43 allhwsupport=1
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

If it still doesn't work as expected, from the terminal:

```
sudo -i
rm /etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf
echo "blacklist b43"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us the result.

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` asks eth0 to start automatically, however, you are using wireless. Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change the file to comment out the eth0 stanza:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot and test.

Comment: Ok, I removed Wicd. I have created that .conf file and added the line.
When I rebooted the error message changed to:
'[16.461422] b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog. 10, Type 8 (LCN), Revision 1)'

Sorry for the formatting I don't know how to add paragraph gaps. Before it boots up it still says 'Booting system without network configuration' but I can still get online after I manually start the Network Manager with Terminal.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Ok, I tried the second suggestion @Chili555 I got a different message on start up '[16.803436] Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by moudule para m allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1'

Comment: Please see my edit. We will blacklist b43 _and_ ssb.

Comment: Ok thank you, I blacklisted b43 and ssb as suggested. After rebooting I didn't get ANY error message until the Ubuntu boot screen (which took longer than usual) along with the message 'Waiting for network configuration' It then booted without the Network Manager again. But I could start it in the Terminal.

Comment: Before you start NM by terminal is it actually running? ps aux | grep -i network Or is it restarting NM that works? What is your terminal command actually? What does this say? cat /etc/network/interfaces Thanks.

Comment: When I first boot up there is no network icon on the top right. Previously I was typing `gksu service network-manager start` in the terminal.
However whilst I was putting the commands you asked, the icon eventually popped up and the network connected on it's own.
When i first booted the result of 'ps aux | grep -i network' was: 138  0.0  0.0   4684   804 pts/11   S+   16:52   0:00 grep --color=auto -i network The result of cat/etc/network/interfaces: auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

Comment: After the network connects the output of the first command is: root      2312  0.4  0.3  52896  6904 ?        Ssl  16:53   0:00 NetworkManager
continued in next comment...

Comment: root 2349  0.0  0.1   5516  3048 ?S    16:53   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf /run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-c448f228-2aaf-44e2-a1b7-2a5c1d5c39fa-wlan0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf wlan0 nobody 2355  0.0  0.0   5556  1396 ? S16:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/

Comment: network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d 2494  0.0  0.0   4688   804 pts/11   S+   16:54   0:00 grep --color=auto -i network

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: thank you very much for all your help. That seems to have fixed the issue. There is a message that flashes up before Ubuntu boot screen. I didn't manage to capture it but it was something about brcmsmac. Anyway, it all seems fine and connects. Thank you again.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a blank file, simply do `touch /etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf`. I'm assuming you'll need to add stuff to that file, and opening it in vim, nano or any other editor will automatically create it upon save.

Comment: When I try this it says 'no such file or directory'