# Grub can't be saved after modification

Tags: grub2, brightness

I have Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit machine on my lenovo g580. Default brightness keys are not working and can't decrease brightness in settings also. The brightness has been fixed at maximum. I followed few similar questions and modified grub document in `/etc/default/grub`, but I'm not being able to save this file after modification. Even though I have logged in as admin.It shows "You do not have the necessary permission to save the file", when I tried "save as" in the same location with the same name. 
What should I do to decrease brightness? Please help.

Comment: How did you try editing `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Open the Terminal app (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Type `gksudo gedit`
- Type your password when asked for it (it will not show nothing, even asterisks) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Text editor will open up
- Then select *Open* and open the file to edit
- Edit the file
- Save the file

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple line : `quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor` to grub

1. `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Replace `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"`
3. `sudo update-grub && sudo reboot`

It worked on:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Asus U31SD-XH51 )
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Dell 14z)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Lenovo g500, remove `nomodeset` and it will work fine)

---

You could try adding a line to `/etc/rc.local` that will set the desired brightness level. To edit the file, run `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and add following line:

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Substitute the `X` by the desired brightness level.

Comment: I did all the things you specified. But still not working. Downloaded an app called "Brightness Controller". Even that is not working. And i don't have rc.local in the above given location. I found that in /etc/rc2.d/S99rc.local . But not getting where should I add the code that you have given. And thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Yeah I had.. Now I'm using Windows 7, thinking of switching back to Ubuntu..