# Modifying pulseaudio daemon.conf in /ect/pulse

Tags: filesystem

I'm trying to modify the pulse audio Daemon.conf located in `/ect/pulse`. I'm having no luck as the folder is read only.

When I open the file using gksudo or sudoedit in terminal, nothing comes up, and if I attempt to save, with gksudo gedit, It notifies me:

```
cannot find the file "/ect/pulse/daemon.conf"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: '*It notifies me: "cannot find the file "/ect/pulse/daemon.conf"".*' If that's exactly what it said, it means you're misspelling `/etc` as `/ect`.

Comment: Haha, brilliant. Well now I'm blushing. Makes so much sense why i was having such a nightmare, a simple mistype.

Answer (score 1):

I found that typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, typing `gksudo`, entering `gedit`, clicking open, browsing manually to the file, modifying and then saving fixed my issue.

Navigating to it using the terminal wasnt working. **AS I WAS MIS-SPELLING ETC AS ECT...**

Thanks Eliah Kagan for [pointing it out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608240/modifying-pulseaudio-daemon-conf-cannot-get-permissions#comment852500_608240).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is to copy the file to your home directory and modify it there.

```
cp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ~/.pulse/daemon.conf
```