# Installing nvidia graphics card leads to "low graphics mode" A driver problem

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system and everything worked fine until I tried to install a graphics card (nvidia gt 630). I put the graphics card in the computer and plugged the monitor into the card and there was no input. The monitor recognized that it was plugged in but was receiving no input. Then I plugged the monitor into the port for the on board graphics and the system was running in low graphics mode. I've tried installing the nvidia drivers multiple times and still cannot get anything to show in the additional drivers menu.

I tried installing the driver with:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304-updates
```

The problem seems to be that the driver isn't being installed and I don't have the standard driver that usually comes with ubuntu. The only graphics driver I see on the list there is the Intel one.

output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatable controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0581 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

output of lspci is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. And how and which drivers do you install?

Comment: Please read my comment again carefully.

Comment: I do not see any Nvidia adapter there. Please add also output of `lspci`.

Comment: There is no Nvidia adapter, or it is disabled in bios.

Comment: How would I check if its disabled in the bios and if it is how do I enable it

Comment: It doesn't seem to have the nouveau driver, that seems important

Answer (score 0):

First of all `nvidia-304-updates` is a wrong driver for your card.
Install the correct one this way

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and reboot. If the adapter still is not detected, try [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/686646/167850).

Comment: I dont seem to have an etc\X11\xorg.conf file that is mentioned in that solution and I am being denied the ability to make one. The closest thing is etc\X11\xorg.conf.failsafe which appears to be required to revert to on board graphics in case something goes wrong.

Comment: You can create this file. But in Ubuntu it is located at `/usr/share/X11`. In `/etc/X11` it will work as well.

Comment: whenever I try to create the file or move the file into that folder it is saying permission denied because root is the owner of the folder

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files

Comment: I got that file set up and rebooted the computer but it still has the same problem

Comment: I did this and the graphics card appears to work although now the keyboard isnt working. It worked as the computer was booting up but as soon as the os appears it stops

Comment: @Pilot6 : Even if '^nvidia.*' would be better ... helpful answer - so +1 for you ! =)

Comment: @cl-netbox Regular expression is really better in 99% of cases. But for nvidia it is OK this way.

Comment: @Pilot6 : yes - as we learned from Rmano the other day ... =)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work after install and reboot for me, until I turned off Intel graphics acceleration in BIOS. Apparently that option conflicts if you just use a dedicated Nvidia card.