# How to run tmux/screen with systemd > 230?

Tags: systemd, tmux, gnu-screen

I run 16.04 and `systemd` now kills `tmux` when the user disconnects ([summary of the change](http://news.dieweltistgarnichtso.net/posts/systemd-breaks-screen-tmux-nohup.html)).

**Is there a way to run `tmux` or `screen` (or any similar program) with `systemd` 230?** I read all the heated disussion about pros and cons of the behavious but no solution was suggested.

(I see the behaviour in 229 as well)

Comment: That's odd - I have `systemd-229-4ubuntu7` (from xenial-updates) and I don't see this behaviour. Anyway, this behaviour has already been reverted in [Debian's `systemd-230-2`](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-systemd/systemd.git/commit/?id=c11c9a4), so it'll probably be reverted in Ubuntu soon too.

Comment: https://www.mirbsd.org/~tg/Debs/dists/jessie/wtf/Pkgs/mirabilos-support/ has prevent-systemd-* packages that allow you to install and use sysvinit as earlier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **Ubuntu 18.04** with **systemd version 237**, none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

The solution that worked for me was to

- edit the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
- uncomment `KillExlcudeUsers`
- add a space separated list of users (e.g., `KillExlcudeUsers=root user1 user2`)

Answer (score 21):

The proper solution is to disable the offending systemd behavior system-wide.

Edit [`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/logind.conf.5.html) ([you must sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/92379/75668), of course) and set

```
KillUserProcesses=no
```

You can also put this setting in a separate file, e.g. `/etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/99-dont-kill-user-processes.conf`.

Then restart `systemd-logind.service`.

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

Comment: How is the proper solution to a problem specific to one unit to set some system wide setting?

Comment: Because, as you can see from even only reading the question, let alone all of the other discussion elsewhere about this that the question indirectly references, this is _not_ specific to one application.  This is a point that is even in boldface in the question.

Comment: You just need to enable lingering for the user via `loginctl enable-linger <user>`. From `man loginctl`: "If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services."

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 here. This does not work, not even after reboot. Enabling lingering does not either.

Answer (score 15):

Based on @Rinzwind's answer and inspired by a [unit description](https://github.com/zoqaeski/systemd-user-units/blob/master/user/tmux.service) the best I could find is to use TaaS (Tmux as a Service) - a generic detached instance of `tmux`one reattaches to.

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/tmux@.service

[Unit]
Description=tmux default session (detached)
Documentation=man:tmux(1)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s %I
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-server
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multiplexer.target

# systemctl start tmux@instanceone.service
# systemctl start tmux@instancetwo.service
# tmux list-sessions

instanceone: 1 windows (created Sun Jul 24 00:52:15 2016) [193x49]
instancetwo: 1 windows (created Sun Jul 24 00:52:19 2016) [193x49]

# tmux attach-session -t instanceone

(instanceone)#
```

Comment: This is neat but I can't for the life of me figure out why you'd use it! :)

Comment: @sarnold: to be able to control applications which start with a console, but which are suppose to be running at boot time. Minecraft is one example.

Answer (score 7):

[RemainAfterExit=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

> Takes a boolean value that specifies whether the service shall be considered active even when all its processes exited. Defaults to no.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted and +1 your answer as it provides the core of the solution. Would you know if it is usable in an interactive mode (by launching `tmux` interactively, as opposed to my answer)?

Comment: doubt it. systemd probably will not care about your tmux unless you tell systemd it should :-P (their approach to this is rather single-minded.... it seems like it is their way or no way.) You need a unit description like you posted. Feel free to accept yours and/or expand yours ;-) I dont need the rep >:-D

Comment: This answer needs more detail such as where to use that setting.

Comment: Sure but the answer is going to be a copy/paste of the manual page ;-)

Comment: @WoJ You can make an alias for `tmux` to start as `systemd-run --remain-after-exit tmux` (or maybe even with `--scope --user` flags).

Answer (score 4):

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287282/117599 invoking `tmux` using

```
systemd-run --user --scope tmux
```

should also do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to no longer work in 18.10 cosmic.

Comment: @taneli _what_ doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `Type` of the service to `forking`, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1276822/537390).

Let's assume the service you want to run in `screen` is called `minecraft`. Then you would open `minecraft.service` in a text editor and add or edit the entry `Type=forking` under the section `[Service]`.