# How to edit Network Manager in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: network-manager, text-editor, nano

I discovered a bug in Ubuntu 18.04 in my system which didn't let me connect to PEAP networks. On searching I found the solution was to edit the configuration file of that wireless network. But whenever I try to edit file in system-connections, I get this page:

[image: View of command]

[image: view of nano]

The file opens as a blank and does not show any details. Can anyone please tell me correct command to open and edit the configuration file (with existing details showing)?

Edit: Yes I tried and failed to connect to the given Wi-Fi network which happened after I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04.
The commands I executed were:

```
$ cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ ls #to see list of connections
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ sudo nano <network name>
```

Comment: Have you tried and failed to connect to KIIT-WIFI-NET? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: In a slightly unrelated note, which bug are you taking about? If it is [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839), only *editing* the configuration file most likely won't fix the issue.

Comment: If you are editing an existing file, then most likely you misspelled it when telling nano which file to open..

Comment: Can you write down the command you are using? Also   provide the directory name and file name if possible. Meanwhile, you can try sudo vi filename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files) to get a graphical editor which may be more convenient.

Comment: @chili555 I have edited the question. Please see

Comment: @user2849789 I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you run the command as root? That directory is only accessible to root, IIRC.

Comment: yes @muru I did