# How to edit the /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf file

Tags: files, virtualization, editing

I am trying configure **libvirtd** for Xen default operation.
I need to edit this file:

/etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf

I am new in ubuntu.

Thank u

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Edit the file: `sudo vim /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf`.
2. Navigate to the desired text using your arrow keys.
3. Press `i` to go into insert mode, and edit the configuration.
4. When done editing, press `ESC` and save the file by entering `:wq`

After saving the file, make sure to either restart libvirtd, or reboot your system.

I believe what you're looking to change is the line `#uri_default = "qemu:///system"`. Uncomment that line first, then replace "qemu" by "xen" so that the whole line should read `uri_default = "xen:///system"`.

Note: It is always a good idea to take backups of configuration files before editing. In this case, `sudo cp /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf.bkp` should do the trick, should you ever need to recover that file.

If you're new to Linux, [here's](https://factorpad.com/tech/vim-cheat-sheet.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImv7yioeq4QIVh-d3Ch1ThQhVEAAYASAAEgJJR_D_BwE) a good tutorial on vim.

Comment: @baalili , when i run the command: sudo vim /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf I get this feedback: sudo vim /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf   What I should do ? thank you

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the exact output?

Comment: output:
sudo: vim: command not found

Comment: Looks like **vim** is not installed. Try using **vi** instead of **vim**.

Comment: Or you could just install **vim**: `sudo apt-get install vim`.