# Unable to edit vsftpd.conf file using ubuntu user

Tags: vsftpd

I tried to edit **VSFTPD.CONF** file but it says I don't have permission. I was logged in root user "ubuntu".

Can anyone help to figure out and resolve my problem.

Comment: please add the result of `ls -l vsftpd.conf` from the place the file is located. And the command you used to start editing it.

Comment: `ubuntu` itself is not the root user - to temporarily become root use `sudo` - see [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: Need to use the `sudo` along with the command `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, as a result, to edit use the command: `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf`