# Remove path from $PATH

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash

I'm newbie here and unknowingly i added some un necessary paths (like 2 times java ) to

```
$PATH
```

I tried many solution but they remove until i'm active. If i `reboot` last path comes again.
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/db/bin`

Here is my output

`/home/nikhil/anaconda3/bin:/home/nikhil/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/db/bin`

How to remove that permanently. Even i log out or reboot or shut down.
I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

This is my  etc/env...

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: There are many places you could have added it - it's hard for us to guess which file(s) you edited (`/etc/environment/`? `/etc/profile`? `~/.bashrc`?)

Comment: @steeldriver I have checked all above. None of these seems wrong.

Comment: Create new user: `sudo adduser user`, login as it using `sudo user` command and `echo $PATH` from it in your question.

Comment: @Gryu I did as you said. But i got same output. 2 times in new user.

Comment: @Gryu 1st path was not there(anaconda) only java was there in new user.

Comment: @NikhilSharma Ok, this means, you've changed something in your system's environment. What is at the end of your bash.bashrc `cat /etc/bash.bashrc `?

Comment: @Gryu See updated post

Comment: Ok, there's nothing. You could remove it from question as it is not messed up.  You could also check what is in your crontab: `crontab -e` and `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: Another place to check is any `.sh` files that might have been sourced from the `/etc/profile.d` directory ex. `grep -w 'PATH' /etc/profile.d/*.sh`

Comment: @Gryu  Just comments(begining with #). Nothing else.

Comment: @steeldriver After running above command i got this `# Expand $PATH to include the directory where snappy applications go.
/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:if [ -n "${PATH##*${snap_bin_path}}" -a -n "${PATH##*${snap_bin_path}:*}" ]; then
/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:    export PATH=$PATH:${snap_bin_path}
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh:export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/db/bin`

Comment: Right - so it's in the `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` file

Comment: @steeldriver What next ?

Comment: Any of (1) edit the file and comment out or delete the erroneous assignment (2) rename the file with a different extension such as `.ignore` or (3) delete the file. Which one is right for your situation is for you to decide.

Comment: @steeldriver Unable to any of these. Delete and rename option not available. Cant open it so no edit

Comment: @NikhilSharma [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: @steeldriver Even after doing as you said. Nothing happened. :-(

Comment: @Gryu I did something and found that on creating new user. Java path is not in path. It means that is not in enviornment. What i should do now ?

Comment: @NikhilSharma after changing files in `/etc/profile.d`, you will need to log out or at least start a new login session (ex. `su -l username`) for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

To find all files with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin` text in your `/` directory, execute the next command:

```
sudo grep -rl "/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin" /
```

To reduce searching time, you could replace `/` by `/etc`, then by `/home/youruserfolder`

Then you could check suspicious files, trying to comment those, where `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin` or something similar is present.