# sysctl.conf open and I can't write in it, it goes boing boing boing

Tags: 18.04, configuration, pycharm

I'm trying to follow [these](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit) instructions to solve some issue with PyCharm. When I open `sysctl.conf`, I can reach the bottom but I can't write. I am greeted with the following Linux "feature":

```
boing
boing
boing
```

What can I do to append this file with this command `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288` and stop the `boing boing boing`?
[image]

Comment: boing boing boing

Comment: Related: [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's your editor that's making that noise, probably because you don't have write access to that file.

I'd suggest using `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` from the terminal.  (Or if you're more familiar with vim, use vim instead of nano.)

/etc/sysctl.conf is only writeable by the root users (for obvious reasons).  So you need to use 'sudo' to act as the root user (super user).