# Make file ready only

Tags: 20.04

When I change this path To>>
enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y1n5.jpg)

I can't save the file.  I get a message that you dont have the permission to save the file please check that you typed the location correctly and try again

Comment: Why the need to include an image? Other users can not search for images and this site is not for just you. Everyone needs to be able to benefit from this. Please remove it and add a copy paste of the important parts of the script.

Comment: You can see from the top line that the make file is opened read-only. Changes anywhere in the file would lead to this error message. Open the file with proper permissions and then make any changes needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0):

Read `man sudo  mkdir chown id` and do something like these **UNTESTED** terminal commands:

```
sudo mkdir --mode=0755 /usr/local/doris
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /usr/local/doris
ls -ld /usr/local/doris
```

OR.

Rerun the `./configure` script and specify a different `INSTALL_DIR`, one that you have write access for.