# How can I add a 51-gcadapter.rules file to the /lib/udev/rules.d folder?

Tags: permissions, udev, dolphin, emulation

I have installed the Dolphin Emulator through the Ubuntu Software App, as no ppa's worked for me. However, my Mayflash gamecube controller adapter is not recognized by the emulator. I set this up previously on Linux Mint by making a 51-gcadapter.rules file and placing this code into it: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="057e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0337", MODE="0666"` once that was placed, the emulator could read the gamecube controller adapter and I could use the controllers.

However, on this Ubuntu install, I cannot write or move any files to the rules folder. I am the only user of this computer and I am wondering if there is some permission issue at play.

Error I receive when trying to write a file in nano editor:

[image: Error I receive when trying to write a file in nano editor]

Comment: As the only user, you should be a member of the `sudo` group - which will allow you to copy or write to files in system directories. See for example [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the details. My issue is that I cannot create a new 51-gcadapter.rules file to my lib/udev/rules.d folder. I have edited the original post with a screenshot of my attempts to add on in Nano. 

If you were able to tell me how to write a new rules file in that folder, I would be very grateful! I will happily provide any details necessary to assist, as I am very new to Linux and don't have much foundational knowledge yet.

Comment: Are you typing `nano /lib/udev/rules.d/51-gcadapter.rules` or `sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/51-gcadapter.rules` here?

Comment: Darn, I now realize I wasn't thinking about the syntax correctly and did not run your 2nd command there - but it did work once I did! The adapter file now exists with the correct code, but the controllers are still not being detected. 

I ended up flatpack installing a brand new version of the emulator, and after a bit of fiddling with settings, it all appears to work! I've learned a lot from you though, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)