# Unable to resolve host

Tags: sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sudo: unable to resolve host (none)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)

When I enter a sudo command in to the terminal I get an error. Just before it asks for a password it says:

> sudo: unable to resolve host harris-laptop

I never had this problem before I changed my computer's name. How can I stop the message showing?