# Problems with network connection: "sudo: unable to resolve host (none)"

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sudo: unable to resolve host (none)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS lost Internet connection. It just acts like it has lost Internet connection.

When I go to terminal in says: `user@(none)`. When I run any `sudo` command, it says

> sudo: unable to resolve host (none)

If I try Firefox, nothing happens. But when I try pinging, it responds fine (but only if it has been pointed to a IP address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, enter this line into the terminal:

nano /etc/hostname

And tell me what it says :)

Comment: Actually it is blank =D

Comment: Then, restart your computer, enter the "recovery mode" in your start-up, and when you are in there, select the option where you can use the command line as "root". From there (note this down), you just type:
`nano /etc/hostname`

then, when you have, enter a pc name / hostname like "computer", and exit with ctrl+x or what it says, to save it. reboot, and try the things again :P

Comment: Did the network work now? If so, no problem!

Comment: Yeah the weird part is that the wired network now shows as Auto Ethernet but works perfectly =D

Comment: Thats because the computer must have a name to be allowed to connect to most networks. If there is no name, no network.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6536/discussion-between-daghostman-dimitrov-and-dennorske)