# unable to edit /etc/hosts file in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: networking, sudo, hostname, hosts

I changed the hostname from default name, set during installation to something short and nice, but didn't change it in `/etc/hosts file`. `/etc/hostname` is changed after restart but `sudo` is not working.

I tried to search for answers on internet. Everybody is suggesting to edit
`/etc/hosts` file and replace:

```
127.0.1.1 <previous name>
```

to:

```
127.0.1.1 <new name>
```

but I cannot change this file either by using:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

It gives an error:

```
sudo:unable to resolve host <new-name>
```

Comment: Have you checked this ? possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none

Comment: since you are having issues, with sudo try to fix it using recovery mode.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode

Comment: You can try starting your computer using a live USB/DVD/CD (preferably using Ubuntu or one of the derivatives) and then editing that hosts file with root privileges from there.

Comment: You can open a commandline editor like _nano_ in terminal with `pkexec` instead of `sudo`. Try this and tell me if it worked, please.

Comment: thanks @Aravinda it looks like the answer to my problem, i am gonna give it a try.

Comment: @ByteCommander your method was the best, it worked like a charm,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `sudo` and its graphical derivates `gksu` and `gksudo` are not working any more, the easiest solution is to use `pkexec` instead to open a command-line editor like `nano` and correct the wrong entries in the specific configuration files (like `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/sudoers`).

Note that `pkexec` works for terminal applications, but needs special configuration to run GUI programs. Therefore you need to use `nano` instead of `gedit`, `mousepad` or whatever your default editor is...

Comment: @MehranAli I converted my comment into an answer as you wrote it solved you problem. Please accept it by clicking on the grey tick right below the vote count on the left. This means "Yes, this is a good answer and solved my problem". Thank you! :-)

Comment: gksudo no longer works as far as I can tell... I think the new thing to use is `sudo -i` (although no doubt it will change in a few years :P

Comment: @Tim `gksu` and `gksudo` work for me on 14.10 Ubuntu plus XFCE...