# how to delete .private

Tags: disk-usage, delete, free

private take alot of space when all my files 70 gb so please help me
df -h

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6            451G  262G  167G  62% /
none                 4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                 2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                392M  476K  392M   1% /run
none                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                 2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none                 100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1            230M   40M  175M  19% /boot
/home/user/.Private  451G  262G  167G  62% /home/user
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are asking how to delete the user's encrypted private directory, right?

Comment: thank you for reply what this line mean please /home/user/.Private  451G  262G  167G  62% /home/user it will delete home/user with it

Comment: that folder will contain all your files (downloads, documents, etc.) and you will lose it if you delete it.

Comment: so why its 260 but my files 70

Answer (score 0):

Providing you can login as root, just type `sudo rm -rf ~/.Private` at the console. Have you tried looking into its contents? It's important to make sure it's not holding anything you might want to keep.

Comment: i tried but it say there is no directory with that name

Comment: Can you show the exact command and error message here?
Also, are you logged into the username "user" account in that computer?

Comment: its not my pc its dedicated server    
-bash: cd: /home/user/.Private: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: /home/user/Private: No such file or directory

Comment: i tried to delete it with ur sudo rm -rf ~/.Private give this sudo: unable to resolve host aflamy

Comment: The second one wasn't going to work since the directory name is ".Private". In the last case, that issue seems to be related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none, check the /etc/hostname file and see if it matches with the proper configuration first, then check back and try to delete the folder again.