# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless not working on Acer Aspire E 15

Tags: wireless, acer, atheros

Can someone help? I've tried the recommended fix used for ubuntu 15.10 and the Qualcomm adapter shown in another thread. Unfortunately it is not working for my acer aspire laptop E15 and the Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless adapter running 15.10. could I be using the wrong terminal commands:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
    wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
    tar -zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
    cd backports-20151120
    make defconfig-ath10k
    make
    sudo make install
```

any help is appreciated

```
 sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath
```

gave the following result:

```
    [    3.831082]  [<ffffffff8107b3d6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
    [    3.831085]  [<ffffffff8107b465>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
    [    3.831216]  [<ffffffff817f02b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
    [    3.832832]  [<ffffffff8107b3d6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
    [    3.832835]  [<ffffffff8107b465>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
    [    3.832962]  [<ffffffff817f02b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
    [   29.961100] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
    [   30.502577] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
    [   30.502604] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
    [   30.502608] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
    [   30.502616] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
    [   30.502619] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
    [   30.502626] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
    [   30.502628] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
    [   30.502636] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
    [   30.502638] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
    [   30.502645] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
    [   30.502647] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
    [   30.502650] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
    [   30.502652] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
    [   49.791690] Modules linked in: bnep rtsx_usb_ms memstick intel_rapl iosf_mbi 
    x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp uvcvideo joydev videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi ath10k_pci(OE) acer_wmi hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_generic videobuf2_core sparse_keymap coretemp v4l2_common ath10k_core(OE) kvm_intel videodev snd_hda_intel btusb snd_hda_codec ath(OE) media mac80211(OE) btrtl btbcm cfg80211(OE) kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep btintel snd_pcm bluetooth compat(OE) input_leds snd_seq_midi serio_raw snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq lpc_ich snd_seq_device snd_timer dell_smo8800 snd 8250_dw i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core dw_dmac dw_dmac_core soundcore spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_pad mei_me mei shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 drbg ansi_cprng
    [   49.791778]  [<ffffffff8107b3d6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
    [   49.791781]  [<ffffffff8107b465>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
    [   49.791922]  [<ffffffff817f02b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
```

-

```
    ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/
```

says, it couldn't find the file, no access possible

```
    sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath10k

    [   25.546049] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
    [   26.073997] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
    [   26.129087] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: invalid firmware magic
    [   26.129111] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
    [   26.129114] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
    [   26.129123] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
    [   26.129126] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
    [   26.129134] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
    [   26.129137] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
    [   26.129146] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
    [   26.129148] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
    [   26.129150] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
    [   26.129153] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
    [   47.742934] Modules linked in: bnep rtsx_usb_ms memstick snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic uvcvideo snd_hda_intel hid_multitouch videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops joydev intel_rapl videobuf2_core snd_hda_codec iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp acer_wmi v4l2_common sparse_keymap coretemp videodev snd_hda_core snd_hwdep media kvm_intel btusb snd_pcm kvm ath10k_pci(OE) btrtl btbcm ath10k_core(OE) btintel ath(OE) bluetooth mac80211(OE) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event input_leds snd_rawmidi snd_seq serio_raw cfg80211(OE) snd_seq_device snd_timer lpc_ich mei_me mei snd compat(OE) soundcore dell_smo8800 dw_dmac dw_dmac_core i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core 8250_dw spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_pad shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 jitterentropy_rng
```

-

```
    cat /sys/module/ath10k_core/parameters/skip_otp
```

shows N

```
    ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
```

shows this now

```
    board.bin       firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1
    board.bin.1     firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1.1
    board.bin.2     firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1.2
    board.bin.3     firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1.3
    board.bin.4     firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1.4
    board.bin.5     firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1.5
    firmware-5.bin
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Also edit to add `ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing needed firmware and missed a parameter setting

```
sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
sudo cp firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 firmware-5.bin
```

To set the parameter

```
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
```

EDIT: Now with kernel 4.3.3 installed,

```
cd backports-20151120
make clean
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately it didn't work. Is there sth else I can do?

Comment: Edit the question to include `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath10k`

Comment: `cat /sys/module/ath10k_core/parameters/skip_otp` might show something and does `ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0` show anything now?

Comment: See edit to set parameter

Comment: I set the parameter, it's now Y

Nothing changed after reboot. What else can I try?

Comment: Could you paste your `/var/log/dmesg` at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL as something else is going on with the kernel

Comment: You could try chili555's answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/715044/300665) but it should do the same, strange as that question involves an Acer Aspire also.  You might want to shutdown the computer then restart rather than reboot

Comment: thx Jeremy31

Can I also paste my dmesg? /var/log/dmesg says that I've no authorization.

Did both - restart and reboot, no results

Comment: See if `dmesg > dmesg.txt` works and then paste the contents of dmesg.txt at paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: it's doing nothing. what about        dmesg k

Comment: It won't show it doing anything but it will create a dmesg.txt file in whatever directory your terminal is in, by default it is in your home folder

Comment: ahhh you're right. Sorry I'm new to this. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: Can you paste the contents?

Comment: yes I did it yesterday before my last comment, do you need a reference?

Comment: It should have given a URL to post

Comment: you mean this - http://paste.ubuntu.com/14570625/

Comment: Download [this](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.3-wily/linux-image-4.3.3-040303-generic_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_amd64.deb), [this](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.3-040303_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_all.deb), and [this](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.3-040303-generic_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_amd64.deb) install and reboot.  Your dmesg shows that you are experiencing a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1513648) and the 4.3.3 kernel should fix it

Comment: thx, I did what you asked, nothing changed - I created a new dmesg.txt:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14589640/

Comment: Post a link to `dmesg | grep ath10k`

Comment: what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Should have printed messages to the terminal window.  `modinfo ath10k | grep -i alias`

Comment: dmesg | grep ath10k    shows noting and     modinfo ath10k | grep -i alias      says that: modinfo: ERROR: Module ath10k not found.

Comment: Sorry `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep -i alias`

Comment: no worries
`alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000040sv*sd*bc*sc*i*`
`alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*`
`alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000041sv*sd*bc*sc*i*`
`alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*`

Comment: Hey Jeremy31, everything ok? do you have any other idea?

Comment: Is this installed UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: I changed UEFI to Legacy in BIOS or I'd have this message - no bootable device

Comment: You can't switch it that easily, see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_Legacy_mode)  It was stated in the bug report for this card that a couple people had to switch from UEFI to legacy to get the card to work

Comment: @jeremy31 in this comment thread you suggest using chilli555's answer in another stackexchange post, remarking that it should do the same thing. Thought you might be curious to know that his solution worked for me where this one did not. I'm on an Acer Aspire e5-573G. Thanks for your help here (and for your related posts in the Arch forums)