# Wifi is not working on an Acer-Aspire E 15 (Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel: 4.4.0-21-generic)

Tags: networking, wireless, acer, 16.04, atheros

I can't get the WiFi working on my new Acer-Aspire E15. It's only running Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel: 4.4.0-21-generic with no dual-boot.

```
lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
```

and

```
lshw -C network

*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 15
   serial: 2c:60:0c:f3:26:79
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.178.53 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1204000-c1204fff memory:c1200000-c1203fff


*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16033602/) is the result from the [wireless-info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205), posted on paste.ubuntu.com

I tried different fixes which I found after some googling like ([this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721049/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-acer-aspire-e-15)), but none of them worked.
Can someone help me identify and solve this problem?

*Edit:*

```
modinfo ath10k_pci | grep backport
version:        backported from Linux (next-20151120-0-ga78de01) using backports backports-20151120-0-g906a6b3
```

Comment: Post the result of `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep backport`

Comment: posted as an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have backports installed and they are not needed in 16.04, so we need to uninstall

```
cd backports-20151120
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot and wifi should work if the firmware has been installed

Not many people have more than one version of backports so you can use the autocomplete that is built into terminal
Type `cd backports` then press TAB and it should finish the command for you.  Then once in the backports directory run the `sudo make uninstall` to uninstall backports and reboot

Comment: I am also having this issue and followed the instructions you said . But for my case it is saying `cd: backports-20151119: No such file or directory` ... What should I do now?

Comment: for me, it wasn't that exact directory either. It was named slightly different..

Comment: @code.prio I edited my answer to include info about autocomplete that may help you

Comment: @t.rathjen that would be odd, what was the folder named?

Comment: yes ... I also did not get any auto completion .. and @t.rathjen can you please share how to get this folder name ?? And Jeremy31 do you know what it could be??? Please...

Comment: I found it with auto-completion. It was named 'backports-20151120-*' but I don't recall it anymore

Comment: Well, In my case there was not any auto completed result ... I tried just now as you said . No Luck .

Comment: @Jeremy31 where it actually located ?? I am trying to search this kind of backports folder all around the computer ?? is it in /bin ?

Comment: @code.prio  Did you install backports?  It isn't included

Comment: No , I did not.... it is a fresh installation. With kernel 4.4.0-22-generic and ubuntu 16.04 on aspire e 15 .

Comment: @code.prio you should start a new question.  Be sure to include terminal results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k`

Comment: Just as you said sir , http://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15

Answer (score 0):

Just in case for anyone in a similar situation:

Update to the 4.8 kernel

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04`

Then reboot.

I posted my issue to the ubuntu forums [HERE](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354276)