# Wifi wont work with Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, connection

I am currently unable to find any wifi connections in Ubuntu. It works fine on Windows 10, however. Ive scoured the internet, but all of the posts are extremely old and i appear to be the only user with this problem. Im on the newest released version, 6.30.223.248 . Also, assume i have very little experience, because i have no idea what im doing.

I entered 
    sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 15
   serial: 2c:60:0c:81:c0:dd
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.252 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c4204000-c4204fff memory:c4200000-c4203fff
*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: Qualcomm Atheros
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:53 memory:c4000000-c41fffff
```

entering lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net comes back with

```
 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:098a]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:1806]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

entering dmesg | grep ath returns

```
 [    9.909508] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
 [   10.152414] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
 [   10.152427] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
 [   10.152430] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
 [   10.152437] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
 [   10.152440] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
 [   10.152447] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
 [   10.152449] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
 [   10.152456] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
 [   10.152458] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
 [   10.152465] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
 [   10.152467] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
 [   10.152470] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
 [   10.152472] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation Duplicate?

Comment: ive actually tried this already.

Comment: Please check here. Exact same symptoms and you need the same fix: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15

Answer (score 1):

I just answered the same question.

Dont worry just enter your terminal and enter : sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

It should work again :)

Tell me if it doesn't

Comment: That's for a broadcom driver... He doesn't have a broadcom device.

Comment: this did not work.