# Ubuntu 16.04: installing atheros QCA9377 wireless driver makes booting problems

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I download and install the QCA9377 driver(wifi 802.11ac) from
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
 for my  Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.
Even though the wi-fi works ok, I have booting problem.
It will cause boot process to fail every other time.
I mean  power on, not restart.
I use text mode to see the boot messages, sometimes, it
Ubuntu will do something after a fail boot,
So it becomes one time of success, the next time failure which means I have to power on, power off then power on to get into the system.

During booting process, sometimes it says

> Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: Not all CPUs entered broadcast
>   exception handler

sometimes it hangs after RFKill

I just follow the following link step by step from AskUbuntu:
[No Wifi in Qualcom Atheros - Ubuntu 16.04 - Acer Aspire E 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp *  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd /lib/firamware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1  firmware-5.bin
```

If I remove the contents in /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
then I can boot into the system without hanging, so the
firmware problem is confirmed. To prove this, I even reinstall the system, update but without installing
any other programs.

What should I do to make the driver work? there are many new notebook using this wifi interface.

p.s.
My notebook is Lenovo idealpad 300 151SK,
cpu Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
System Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
Linux kernel 4.4.0-22

Comment: After removing the driver and reinstalling it again, and updating Ubuntu. The booting issue is gone.

Comment: There are two errors in your script:

Line 7: cp should be cp -av
Line 8: /lib/fir(a)mware -> /lib/firmware