# can't connect wifi on ubuntu 16.04 dual boot windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, xubuntu

I've just installed ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10. Unfortunately I can't connect wifi on ubuntu, but wifi on windows still works. it says wifi disabled and I can't enable wifi. anyone help me to solve this problem?
ps. my wireless card is Qualcomm

Answer (score -1):

I think there are similar questions. What I found online says that the problem is with some missing firmware.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Sources:

[Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface. Atheros [168c:003e] device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface-atheros-168c003e-dev)

[No Wifi in Qualcom Atheros - Ubuntu 16.04 - Acer Aspire E 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15)