# Specific WIFI not working Qualcom Atheros

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, atheros

I have a Lenovo V110 running on Ubuntu 16.04

The WIFI was working perfectly until a few days ago. Suddenly a specific WIFI which use to work before has stopped working. Other Wifi work fine in my laptop and this particular wifi works on other laptops but just not on my laptpo.

After a lot of debugging I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15) question so I followed these commands to get this -

Command

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k
```

Output

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3841]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
[   12.056523] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.066565] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   15.031654] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   15.031657] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   15.263541] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

The stack trace above has this error line -

```
Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
```

Other useful info -

Command

```
uname -r
```

Output

```
4.4.0-57-generic
```

Command

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Output

```
 *-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Qualcomm Atheros
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 30
   serial: cc:b0:da:a6:8c:0d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:280 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 15
   serial: 54:ee:75:ab:02:4a
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.20.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:277 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d1204000-d1204fff memory:d1200000-d1203fff
```

Command

```
rfkill list all
```

Output

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

Command

```
ifdown wlp2s0
```

Output

```
Unknown interface wlp2s0
```

Command

```
sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces
```

Output

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Some other things I've noticed while connected to that specific Wifi which is not working are -

1. I'm able to get an IP address.
2. I'm able to ping that IP address.
3. I'm not able to ping the default gateway found using `routes` command.
4. I'm not able to ping any external address.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** Still experiencing these problems with some other WiFi as well. Still no solution found.

Comment: Reload the driver `sudo rmmod ath10k_pci
&& sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci`

Comment: @GAD3R reloaded but no change.