# Replaced wireless adapter files in Ubuntu, now Windows can't find my wireless adapter

Tags: 14.04, command-line, drivers, wireless, windows-10

Dual booting with Windows 10. I've only installed Ubuntu like last week. So basically the issue started with Ubuntu not having wireless internet. I found the issue described in this topic [No Wifi in Qualcom Atheros - Ubuntu 16.04 - Acer Aspire E 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15)

I could follow all the commands up until:

```
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1  firmware-5.bin
```

Since it couldn't find the file/directory. I looked further. I found this topic with a similar problem https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2308578

I executed these commands

```
sudo rm -r /lib/firmware/ath10k
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
```

Oh now I have all the files in that git repository. Wireless still didn't work but I rebooted and went on my Windows.

**PROBLEM:**

And I see now that after doing sudo rm and deleting my initial configuration I somehow messed up my wireless on the Windows side. Now I can't go wireless and it doesn't even detect my wireless adapter in the device manager, even when I scan. I tried re-installing the wireless adapter but nothing changes. Now I'm stuck without wireless.

Maybe that this information helps

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3854]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
[   12.786686] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.025131] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   15.534724] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid bc1e1d0e-1081-4997-af24-68e082737f2e)
[   15.534730] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 0.0 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   15.534732] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   15.536863] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware register dump:
[   15.536865] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x05020000 0x00000000 0x000A091C 0x00000009
[   15.536866] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x000A091C 0x00050730 0x00000010 0x00000003
[   15.536868] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [08]: 0x00000001 0x004173B0 0x00400000 0x00421370
[   15.536869] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[   15.536870] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x00914761 0x00000000 0x00000000
[   15.536871] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [20]: 0x400A091C 0x0040EA28 0x00419980 0x004212E8
[   15.536872] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [24]: 0x800A0D0A 0x0040EA88 0xFFFFFFFF 0xC00A091C
[   15.536874] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [28]: 0x800A0614 0x0040EAA8 0x0041FA10 0x00420170
[   15.536875] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [32]: 0x80910829 0x0040EAC8 0x00000000 0x00400600
[   15.536876] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [36]: 0x80910927 0x0040EB08 0x00000000 0xFFF08041
[   15.536877] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [40]: 0x8091114E 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00400600
[   15.536878] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [44]: 0x8091122D 0x0040EB48 0x00000000 0x00400600
[   15.536879] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [48]: 0x40910024 0x0040EB78 0x0040AB98 0x0040AB98
[   15.536880] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [52]: 0x00000000 0x0040EB98 0x009BB001 0x00040020
[   15.536882] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [56]: 0x8091114E 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00400600
[   16.523695] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to receive control response completion, polling..
[   17.523512] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: ctl_resp never came in (-110)
[   17.523515] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to connect to HTC: -110
[   17.524004] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not init core (-110)
[   17.524034] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
[   17.535587] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
```

Comment: Please don't write "SOLVED" in the question. Write your own answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

The firmware was added to the linux-firmware package in Ubuntu 16.04 since chili555's answer.   Go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/all/linux-firmware/download select a mirror to download from and install.
Shutdown and do a cold boot

Comment: I wanted to add that I'm running 14.04, should I still try that?

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it in my case was using wkennington's repository for the ath10k files instead of kvalo's.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)