# Wifi keeps getting disconnected in ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: wireless, 18.04, firmware

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my new Dell XPS 13 9370. Everything seems to be working except for wi-fi. It keeps getting disconnected. Quick search gave me the following link:

[No Wifi in Qualcom Atheros - Ubuntu 16.04 - Acer Aspire E 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15)

It turns there is some problem with the firmware because the device seems to be new and is not yet integrated into the *linux-firmware*.

The following is the output of the command that was run in the above question:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:143a]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
[    2.701863] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.703835] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.981571] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.981584] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.985220] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:143a
[    2.985223] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.986160] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    3.051685] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[    3.216685] Modules linked in: hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_realtek(+) snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_skl dell_laptop(+) dell_smbios_smm dcdbas snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc ath10k_pci ath10k_core aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd ath glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate mac80211 intel_rapl_perf cfg80211 rtsx_pci_ms memstick idma64 virt_dma joydev input_leds snd_hda_intel serio_raw snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core dell_smbios_wmi dell_wmi snd_hwdep dell_smbios snd_pcm dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device
[    3.631258] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    3.634258] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    3.634839] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    3.725573] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.714843] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    4.717917] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   84.170108] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[   84.173081] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
```

It doesn't specify the exact driver version in the above error message (`Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2`)

Answer (score 0):

Try the firmware listed on [kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/firmware?s%5b%5d=qca6174) from [kvalo/ath10k-firmware](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware). Follow the instructions to replace your existing one with it. Also, [this manual](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Atheros_QCA6174) from Gentoo may be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure as to how to build kernels. Could you please provide some links or tutorials which explain this?

Comment: @kvmanohar You do not need to build kernel. Just copy firmware from git rep to your `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/` dir.

Comment: I did try that from the link I provided. That doesn't seem to help either

Comment: Just curious. Is this problem persistant even with other versions of ubuntu as well? Since I'm using 18.04 LTS. I'm just wondering if downgrading to 17.04 or 16.04 would work?