# No WiFi adapter found Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

my WiFi adapter Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565/AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter.doesn't work or even appear in the system settings.I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with a dual boot with windows 10.the WiFi adapter works in windows. 
output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0803]
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0803]
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

sudo rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network  

   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 15
   serial: 1c:39:47:53:6c:4b
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:-2147483648 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1104000-c1104fff memory:c1100000-c1103fff
 *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c1000000-c107ffff memory:c1080000-c108ffff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: enp0s20u1
   serial: 76:f5:dc:14:1d:16
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.239 link=yes multicast=yes
```

dmesg | grep ath9k

```
[   21.252360] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A: not connected
[   21.252404] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: request_irq failed
[   21.252423] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -107
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: It is not the full output.

Comment: it is the acer e5 573 laptop

Comment: The `-A3` should show the module in use or some other device.

Comment: i'm sorry pilot6  i don't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean that we need the full output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 `

Comment: it only shows this      03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0803]
 Kernel modules: ath9k

Comment: here is the output of the script a user from Ubuntu forums told me to use http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dHC8F3Gby9/

Answer (score 0):

Pay you attention command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` output contains no line `Kernel driver in use`. Just do

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Next check the wireless module for soft and hard block

```
sudo rfkill list
```

As your laptop is Acer, try

```
echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf
```

Reboot the laptop and try `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `sudo rfkill list` again.

If nothing helps try [No Wifi on Acer Aspire E5 573 on any Linux Platform](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715037/no-wifi-on-acer-aspire-e5-573-on-any-linux-platform).

And finally try solution from post #22 from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343?comments=all).

ADDENDUM

Do

```
cd
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo rm -rf /lib/firmware/ath10k
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
sudo chmod +x /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/*
sudo chmod +x /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot laptop.

ADDENDUM #2

Try

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Reboot laptop.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79960/discussion-on-answer-by-wiking-no-wifi-adapter-found-ubuntu-18-04).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ubuntu 17 and i solved following the below steps.

First of all, I tried to download the network kernel from site --> https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/17.10/ubuntu-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb.html

If your architecture is x64,

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Then, I saw the configuration of network service

```
 cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

By default, there are

```
 [main]`
 plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

 [ifupdown]
 managed=false

 [device]
 wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

if it is different of yours, change it.

Then, you need to restart the kernel configuration.

```
  sudo service network-manager restart
```

Reboot the computer.

On bios, change the boot secure:

```
boot secure: disabled   ->    boot secure: enabled
```

And ok.

Works in ubuntu 17, Positivo Stilo XCi7660.

bye

Answer (score 0):

As I had problems with the WiFi network and Atheros driver on ubuntu I asked for advice also on askubunt. The laptop did not show a WiFi network. On the internet, tips like installing drivers for a WiFi adapter didn’t help.
I solved the problem by simply resetting the router. So it was not a problem in the laptop or ubuntu but the router. Try resetting the router or resetting the router to factory settings.
Also if you've installed linux on your laptop multiple times you've probably made a mess with secure boot and maybe that's why you can't have WiFi on ubuntu if secure boot is enabled. Therefore, before a clean new installation of ubuntu, reset the BIOS / UEFI secure boot to factory settings and reinstall ubuntu.  At least that's how it is on an acer laptop.

Admin sorry I followed up on an old topic but it might help someone.