# WiFi is disconnecting intermittently on ACER E5-573G with a Linux platform

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, acer

I dual booted my Laptop Acer Aspire E5-573G with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and since the first day the WIFI is connecting and disconnecting frequently.
I have been searching in others questions but I do not know to fix it on my own.

From what I have learned from the other questions I leave here the results of the following commands:

1. sudo lspci -v

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at c4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

2. dmesg | grep ath10k

```
[    3.139494] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.472128] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 target 0x05020000 chip_id 0x003820ff sub 11ad:0806
[    3.472131] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.472641] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 42e41877
[    3.539849] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[    5.738498] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    5.757526] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.56 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    5.841254] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.151592] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[  352.551446] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
```

Thanks to all the people that is going to read this post and help me (and to others with the same/similar problem).

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -i cell -A5`, changing wlan0 to your appropriate wireless device. What wireless network do you normally use? Post the output to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema
Thank you very much heynnema, but I have already fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@heynnema
Thank you very much heynnema, but I have already fix the issue.
I have modified this answers "[No Wifi on Acer Aspire E5 573 on any Linux Platform](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715037/no-wifi-on-acer-aspire-e5-573-on-any-linux-platform#715044)" and "https://esc.sh/blog/wifi-issue-on-acer-laptops-running-linux-qualcomm-atheros-device-0042/" and it work for the moment. I didn't want to try before because I don't understand very well what the different files are for, but I've taken a risk and it seems that work.

My solution:

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

and again heynnema thank you very much for help me answering the question.