# Unable to resolve host <name>

Tags: sudo

After I enter `sudo` command in command-line it shows this error :

```
unable to resolve host linux98
```

linux98 is my PC name. i have tried these solution too :
[Error message when I run sudo: unable to resolve host (none)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none?newreg=3415ebcae8684988a71e0ddb9ee5fde3)
and 
[Error message when I run sudo: unable to resolve host (none)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)
but it did'nt solve my problem. please help me !

Comment: Could you include in your question the contents of `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`, please?

Answer (score 1):

That error shows up if you changed host name and `/etc/hosts` was not changes.

`/etc/hosts` will have 7 lines. You need to alter the 2nd word on the 2nd line to `127.0.0.1 linux98`.

You will need to use a live session since `/etc/hosts` needs `sudo` to be able to save changes (`sudo nano /etc/hosts`) and if `sudo` complains ... not going to work.

Comment: Should we reboot tha node afterwards?