# Unable to locate package Greenbone

Tags: apt, 16.04, updates

Hoping someone can explain to me what the problem is with the below screenshot?

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 server on Raspberry PI and I am trying to install Openvas,

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the repository, you can get it at this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mrazavi/+archive/ubuntu/openvas)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mrazavi/openvas && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install greenbone-security-assistant
```

Here is a list of other packages supplied by this PPA

```
greenbone-security-assistant9
openvas-cli 
openvas-libraries
openvas-manager
openvas-scanner 
openvas9-cli 
openvas9-libraries 
openvas9-manager 
openvas9-scanner 
rats
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for you reply. However it is still failing.

Comment: What is the error? Does the PPA add correctly? I don't see why it would fail, the PPA is right there and supports 16.04.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mrazavi/openvas && sudo apt-get update

Yes it adds OK and then asks me to press enter which I do.
I then enter the sudo apt-get install greenbone-security-assistant 

and get 
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install greenbone-security-assistant
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package greenbone-security-assistant

Comment: It can't resolve your host, what is the output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none

Comment: It runs but the first line is
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu

Then it looks like it attempts to update.
When it gets to download.opensuse.org
"N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default."

Comment: What is that PPA? Disable it.

Comment: Its the following ones. 

W: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/OpenVAS:/UNSTABLE:/v5/xUbuntu_12.04/./Release.gpg: Signature by key 74848501FA390C473AFDAC38BED1E87979EAFD54 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/OpenVAS:/UNSTABLE:/v5/xUbuntu_12.04 ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1442587334
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/OpenVAS:/UNSTABLE:/v5/xUbuntu_12.04 ./ Release' is not signed.

Comment: Get rid of that, open `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out any opensuse lines with a `#` at the start, then `sudo apt update`

Comment: That works without error.
Still unable to install Greenbone. With the error "Unable to locate package greenbone-security-assistant"

Comment: Now run the commands to add the PPA in the answer again

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mrazavi/openvas && sudo apt-get update
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~mrazavi/ubuntu/openvas'.
ERROR: '~mrazavi' user or team does not exist.

This is strange its a fresh install too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46454/discussion-between-mark-kirby-and-alex-harding).