# Wireless Intel 7260 disabled on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, iwlwifi

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my DELL 7240 and my WiFi adapter (Intel 7260) seems to be disabled.

I have tried different ways to enable it:

Edited the following file: `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`  adding `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8`, and then added also `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`. However, it didn't work after rebooting.

Continuing on reading from other posts, I have tried `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` which didn't work as well.

I have also downloaded the latest drivers for the Intel driver from https://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/linux-firmware and put under /lib/firmware/ directory, and then rebooted. Still, didn't work.

I have also tried to upgrade my kernel, and do update on everything. Still didn't work.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` :

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4470]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
1:  phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: yes
2:  dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: yes
3:  dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: yes
4:  nfc0: NFC
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

The secure boot is disabled as well.

My kernel is 5.11.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Evan

Comment: You did a lot of wrong things. `wl` is a Broadcom driver and is unrelated. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pilot6. just edited as per your recommendation.

Comment: Your Wi-Fi is hard blocked. Try to reset BIOS, or find a hardware switch button. If that  doesn't help, there is a software way to disable the platform driver that may cause problems. It is NOT a driver problem. All is OK with drivers.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. I tried to reset BIOS but didn't change anything.

I can try with a hardware switch button too the next days.

In case this doesn't work either, do you know which software might help to disable the platform driver that might be causing issues? And how to find this driver?

Comment: It is not software. You need to blacklist `dell_wmi`

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. I tried to blacklist dell_wmi by issuing ```sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell.conf <<< "blacklist dell_wmi" ``` as you mention on this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/937648/wi-fi-is-disabled. This didn't work for me either.

Do you have any other ideas? Could it be that the WiFi card failed?

Answer (score 0):

found on an old page https://dev.getsol.us/T3790 : add the intel_iommu=off kernel boot parameter in GRUB

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1227777)