# Raspberry Pi 3B with Ubuntu Server(CLI) with No Ethernet Recognition and No Wlan0 List

Tags: networking, server, wireless, network-manager, raspberrypi

Everyone!

I'm a totally beginner for Raspberry Pi.

Now I 'm trying to connect raspberry pi 3B with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server to the ethernet and wifi. However the etheret and wifi can not recognized.

**1.First This is My Software and Hardware Device**

・Software(OS): Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server(Not GUI, it is CLI)

・Hardware:

```
   (a)Raspberry Pi 3B

   (b)Lan Cable 

   (C)Pocket Wifi with Wifi to Ethernet Adapter(using lan cable to connect to the raspberry pi 3B) 
      (c-1)Pocket Wifi:  Speed Wi-Fi NEXT W03　HWD34<br>
      (c-2)Wifi to Ethernet Adapter: HWD34 PUA <br>
```

**Official Ubuntu 16.04 Server images:**

・Raspberry Pi 3B: ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz

⇒OS Download from here ↓

http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz

**2.Second These are the Result of the Command**

==<Ehternet>=======================================

**$ sudo ip addr show eth0**

- Image:[Evidence1_sudo ip addr show eth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uRkk.jpg)

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
2: eth0: mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000

link/ether b8:27:eb:6c:ff:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 2001:268:c005:1e0b:ba27:ebff:fe6c:ff76/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
      valid_lft 7176sec preferred_lft 3576sec
inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe6c:ff76/64 scope link
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

---

**$ sudo ifconfig -a**

- Image:[Evidence2_sudo ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXtsQ.jpg)

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr  b8:27:eb:6c:ff:76
inet6 addr:inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe6c:ff76/64 Scope:Link
inet6 addr:2001:268:c005:1e0b:ba27:ebff:fe6c:ff76/64:Global
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1

lo     Link encap: Loopback
inet addr:127.0.01 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
...

---

**$sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces**

***"There is file, but the content is nothing!!"***

**$sudo ifdown eth0**

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
...
Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:6c:ff:76
Sending on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:6c:ff:76
Sending on Socket/fallback

---

**$sudo ifup eth0**

- Image:[Evidence3_$sudo ifup eth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFMuq.jpg)

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
...

Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:6c:ff:76
Sending on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:6c:ff:76
Sending on Socket/fallback

DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe8cd0311)
...

NO DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.

---

==<Wifi>=======================================

**$ iwconfig**

---

The program 'iwconfig' is currently not installed. You can install it
   by typing:
 sudo apt install wireless-tools

---

**$ sudo apt install wireless-tools**

- Image:[Evidence4_$ sudo apt install wireless-tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gPdZ.jpg)

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
Reading Package lists... Done
The following additional package will be installed:
libiw30
The following additional package will be installed:
libiw30 wireless-tools
...

Err1:1 http: //ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf libiw30 armhf 30~pre9-8ubuntu1
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf wireless-tools armhf 30~pre9-8ubuntu1

E: Failured to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/w/wireless-tools/wirelss-tools/wireless-tools/wireless-tools_30~pre9-8ubuntu_armhf.deb
Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'

E:Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing

---

**$ sudo apt-get update**

- Image:[Evidence5_$ sudo apt-get update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOoWU.jpg)

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
Err1:...
Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err2:...

---

**$sudo ifdown wlan0**

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
Unknown interface wlan0

---

**$sudo ifup wlan0**

---

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused
Unknown interface wlan0

---

**3.Third What is About the Ethernet**

This time I'm using  Pocket Wifi to Ethernet Adapter connecting to the raspberry pi 3B by lan cable.

However, when I plug eletronic cord and start the raspbarry pi OS,
The first line on the start-up image will show

---

"Net: Net initialization Skipped
No ethernet found
starting USB..."

---

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: This is the device list:Wifi-Pocket: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC-Speed-Wi-Fi-NEXT-HWD34/dp/B01HR824K6

Comment: Wifi to Ethernet Adapter:https://onlineshop.au.com/disp/CSfLastGoodsPage_001.jsp?GOODS_NO=6204&dispNo=001001007

Comment: Check the answer of this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-user , edit the corresponding files, reboot and repeat sudo ifconfig command.

Comment: kukulo:Thank you very much! I just type "$ nano /etc/hostname" And the add line "127.0.1.1    ubuntu"(my username is ubuntu) ,save the file,then type"sudo reboot",Resultly when I try sudo cammand, no error message like":sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection Refused" appears! Thank you!!

Comment: It apears that it worked out. Could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer of this question:

[Error message 'sudo: unable to resolve host <USER>'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-user)

Type `$ nano /etc/hostname` 
and the add line

`127.0.1.1 ubuntu`  (my hostname is ubuntu) ,save the file,

then type`sudo reboot`.

Comment: Thank for your help!! ;))))Now I 'm step to the next stage, to fix $ sudo-apr-get update which would fetch to fail problem Q_Q