# Explain the parameters before and after @ in the terminal prompt

Tags: 16.04, command-line

What do the values in the prompt mean?

```
alexey511@rgb-3345:~$
```

I know it is a very basic question. But I am struggling with [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none) and I cannot  solve it because of the lack of the basic understanding. After googling I didn't find any explanation. (Certainaly it is hidden somewhere in the documentation and one should read probably hundreds of pages to get there).

I'd appreciate your help. I really like to get knowing with Linux but first steps are somehow not easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The part before the "@"

```
alexey511
```

is your username; check with

```
$ whoami
alexey511
```

The part between "@" and ":"

```
rgb-3345
```

is the hostname:

```
$ hostname
rgb-3345
```

The part between ":" and "$"

```
~
```

is the current working directory, abbreviated to the tilde which is a synonym for your home directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/alexey511
```

And finally the "$" is the actual "prompt" sign, indicating you're a normal user (instead of `root`, in which case it would read "#"), and that command input is expected from you here.

Altogether this is a fairly vanilla shell prompt which is defined and assigned to the environment variable `PS1` like this (without color codes for better readability), usually in the file `~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

If you want to experiment with it, check out this page:

https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/

Answer (score 0):

The prompt in the terminal is set by the variable `PS1`.

`echo $PS1` shows how it is set in your system, and

`man bash` and search for the chapter on `PROMPTING` gets you the possible parameters for the PS prompts.

PS1 is set in `.bashrc` file.