# Dirty filesystem on a VPS

Tags: 18.04, vps

I was alerted to my site, on a VPS, going down by Uptime monitor. I SSHd to it to reboot, which is usually what it needs, and then it all went bad.

Turns out the underlying NAS was rebooting for no apparent reason (according to my service provider) and I rebooted in the middle of that.

I have a dirty file system - but I can't run fsck `fsck from util-linux 2.31.1` and I can't sudo `sudo: unable to resolve host asimov: Resource temporarily unavailable`.

The web interface refuses to respond.

Apparently I have to reboot in recovery mode but all I have is the command line.

Comment: Related: [Error message “sudo: unable to resolve host (none)”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)

Comment: Yes I've been through every post I could dig up on the web on this subject. I only have SSH access and I can't edit anything because I can't sudo. (No, 'asimov' is not in /etc/hosts but I can't change it because I can't edit, because I can't sudo. Which I said in the OP.)

Comment: "sudo: unable to resolve host asimov: Resource temporarily unavailable."  when does that show? Cuz the sudo command should still execute.  like explained here  in comments: https://askubuntu.com/a/524368/15811