# How to install mongodb on the server?

Tags: server, mongodb

Installed the ubuntu 16.04 server.
Next, I try to install mongodb 4.2 according to the instructions from the [official site](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition-using-deb-packages).

After entering the command (step 2)

> echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu
>   xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

I get this error

[image]

> sudo: unable to resolve host sarnormail-vps-10
>
> deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu
>   xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse

Help me figure out what it means?

> sudo: unable to resolve host sarnormail-vps-10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message "sudo: unable to resolve host (none)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none) - note that this is not an error message, and does not stop the command from doing what it's supposed to. It's merely a warning.

Comment: @vidarlo, Thank you, I already understood this and solved the problem.