# ldconfig:unable to resolve

Tags: libraries

**1)**
I need to download and install Data AcQuisition library (DAQ) from the Snort website.
The code itself is well known and no issues there:

```
cd ~/snort_src

git clone https://github.com/snort3/libdaq.git

cd libdaq

./bootstrap

./configure

make

sudo make install
```

**2)**
After installing that I should update shared libraries above:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

And here comes the problem...

**3)**
What ever I try I just can't get pass this "***ldconfig"*** command
Here below is my terminal response:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin


ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo ldconfig
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server: Name or service not known


ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied


ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ su; ldconfig
Password: 
root@ubuntu-server:/home/ubuntu# ldconfig
root@ubuntu-server:/home/ubuntu# 
root@ubuntu-server:/home/ubuntu# exit
exit
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ 


ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo /sbin/ldconfig
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server: Name or service not known
```

**4)**
As I'm very new to all of this (and I just want to install SNORT+GRAFANA)
I got stuck at this point... Hope someone can help me...?

I have already checked some solutions (.bashrc,...) but nothing helped...
and I can't run my SNORT installation, before libraries are OK...

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with your hostname configuration than about `ldconfig` specifically - see for example [Error message “sudo: unable to resolve host (none)”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)

Comment: Thank You so much, when I changed my default code with "nano", error was gone...

127.0.0.1 localhost #Original code
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain ubuntu-server #Changed code

But still not sure if command done anything....
After activating sudo ldconfig I didn't recieve any status, just new line jump..
is that expected ?

Comment: AFAIK that's normal - if you want to "see" something, run it in verbose mode, like `sudo ldconfig -v`

Comment: Yeah...I got to understand that just after posting here... (I'm pretty new..as You can see)..
So ldconfig works fine now THANK YOU VERY MUCH for direct pointing. 
Sill... this didn't solve my SNORT problem....but I'm getting there, step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the ldconfig issue, the solution was offered by Mr.steeldriver in
the comments below:

**AFAIK that's normal - if you want to "see" something, run it in verbose mode, like sudo ldconfig -v – steeldriver 1**

### **THANK YOU VERY MUCH !**

The change reqired as described below:

```
cat /etc/hostname              #You get your hostname here
sudo nano /etc/hosts           #You make changes here (save after CTRL X)

127.0.0.1 localhost #Original code 
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain ubuntu-server #Changed code with hostname
```