# File system check at boot time fails

Tags: boot, grub2, fsck, hostname

My Ubuntu 20.10 installation was showing a blank screen after booting, so I started it in recovery mode and tried `sudo fsck -f /`. The error it gave was:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host dk: Temporary failure in name resolution
fsck from util-linux 2.36
e2fsck 1.45.6
/dev/sda3 unmounted
e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "sudo: unable to resolve host (none)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)

Comment: I tried that. Not working. Besides I think he had a problem in the terminal but my pc is showing this problem while booting

Comment: Following that question now the host problem is gone but remaining problems are still there and the booting process result in a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unmounting the system partition when it's in use is generally not a great idea, particularly when you need to read some of the files on the partition. In order to do this, it may be better to grab your installation media (the USB stick or DVD) for Ubuntu, boot into a Live Session, *then* run the file system check with the `-nf` flags:

```
fsck -nf /dev/sda3
```

| Flag | Meaning | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `n` | dry-run | Check only, do not make changes |
| `f` | force | Force a new check |

If errors are reported afterwards, run `fsck` again without the `n` flag. From there, any issues will hopefully be resolved and the file system will mount properly at boot time.

Comment: I tried running that but the error persists. I tried umount dev/sda3 but system wouldn't allow me. I followed some other questions on askubuntu as well but none of them worked. I will try using usb stick. But is there any other way that I can by pass the whole problem. Right now I'm unable to even login. Will creating another user/host work?

Comment: If the file system is insisting on checking a partition or disk at startup it is because a serious problem is suspected. Yes, you can override it and boot, but it would be irresponsible to do so, particularly if it results in a corrupted file system. You cannot unmount an active partition. Don’t try to cheat the system. Use a Live USB/DVD and check your disk properly. Otherwise you may as well wipe the system clean, reinstall the OS, then restore from last night’s backup.