# Temporary name resolution failure

Tags: networking, server, dns, display-resolution

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on a laptop computer.   Clean install worked fine.   ran apt-get update && apt_get upgrade.  Now network is all "temporary failure in name resolution'. Every other computer on the home network is fine.  This looks like 'fail by default' to me, but 30 years into linux that seems unlikely.  What do i need to check?
/etc/host and /etc/hostname match.
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
gui for ethernet connection is 'Automatic Addresses Only' with DNS Servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Comment: Are you getting the same errors as this question?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343609/sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-hostname-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution  If I do a search on this site I see 205 results.  Might want to check through these and see if something matches exactly your issue:  https://askubuntu.com/search?q=temporary+failure+in+name+resolution

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those.

Comment: This question should have an answer