# How do I change the hostname without a restart?

Tags: restart, hostname

I want to change the OS hostname but I do not want to restart.

I have edited `/etc/hostname` but it requires a restart to get implemented. How to avoid this?

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 692, accepted):

It's easy. Just click the Gear icon (located at upper right corner of the screen), open "About this computer" screen (located at Gear icon ) and edit "Device name".

Or, in a terminal, use the following command:

```
sudo hostname your-new-name
```

This will set the hostname to your-new-name until you restart. See [`man hostname`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/hostname.1) and [How do I change the computer name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name) for further information. Do not use `_` in your name.

**Note**

After a restart your changes in [`/etc/hostname`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/hostname.5) will be used, so (as you said in the question), you should still use

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/hostname
```

(or some other editor) so that file contains the hostname.

To test that the file is set up correctly, run:

```
sudo service hostname start
```

You should also edit `/etc/hosts` and change the line which reads:

```
127.0.1.1     your-old-hostname
```

so that it now contains your new hostname. (This is required otherwise many commands will cease functioning.)

Comment: i dont want to restart

Comment: I know. that's why you should use the 'hostname' command. I just wanted to clarify, that the 'hostname' command does only change the hostname until you restart/crash/etc. Afterwards it will read the name from the file again.

Comment: thanks. that means after changing the hostname we need to restart right.

Comment: Depends. If you entered the command you do not need to restart. The hostname is changed already. But only UNTIL your next restart.

Comment: Note that you also have to change the `/etc/hosts` (see other answers)

Comment: In short, although `hostname` will cause the new name to take immediate effect, it is not "permanent" unless you also change `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`, since those are the files that will be read after a restart or a crash, which of course, you may not be expecting ahead of time.

Comment: I just did these steps on Lubuntu. Now I can't start any programs. Even the power button in the bottom right of the screen doesn't function. Nor Ctrl+Alt+Delete. I can post this only because firefox was already running. I'm going to press the hardware power button now. --update: Had to long press the power button. Everything seems fine now. Hostname successfully changed... but technically a reboot was still required.

Comment: How can I restore original host name w/o restart?

Comment: You have to run "sudo hostname your-original-hostname" in a terminal.
If you do not know it anymore and did not change the above mentioned files yet, you can look it up: "cat /etc/hostname"

Comment: My `/etc/hosts` says `127.0.1.1     localhost`. So you propose to change `localhost` to something?

Comment: That depends on the purpose of your system. If it is just a desktop, feel free to leave it as it is. If it is a server, which is available via an actual domain name, you would want to add this name to the line. `127.0.1.1 localhost localhost.localdomain your-domain.net`

Comment: If you're running postfix for emails then it's a good idea to check the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and the variables for `myhostname` and `mydestination`.

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.  See cloud-init answer(s) below.

Answer (score 313):

## Ubuntu 13.04 onwards

The [`hostnamectl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/hostnamectl.1) command is part of the default installation on both Desktop and Server editions.

It combines setting the hostname via the `hostname` command and editing `/etc/hostname`. As well as setting the static hostname, it can set the "pretty" hostname, which is not used in Ubuntu. Unfortunately, editing `/etc/hosts` still has to be done separately.

```
hostnamectl set-hostname new-hostname
```

This command is part of the [`systemd-services`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/systemd-services) package (which, as of Ubuntu 14.04, also includes the `timedatectl` and `localectl` commands). As Ubuntu migrates to `systemd`, this tool is the future.

Comment: Note this isn't available everywhere.  Just looked on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ARM-7 installation, and `hostnamectl` doesn't exist.  Guess some flavours of Ubuntu aren't using systemd yet.

Comment: @Stéphane the commands are part of the systemd suite, but they are available independently. In this case, 13.04-14.10 don't use systemd as init, by the command is available.

Comment: @muru, you show 2 items are needed: editing of `/etc/hosts` and invoking `hostnamectl`. I think there may have to be a 3rd item which would be similar to `export HOSTNAME=xxx`. Also the order might matter. I have problems invoking`sudo` if the order is wrong. I infer that `sudo` depends upon `/etc/hosts` so it is better to do that one first if either of the other 2 operations require `sudo`.

Comment: @H2ONaCl the shell variable is set on startup, just open another shell and the hostname variable should be fine. As for sudo, the error about hostname resolution has never actually prevented me from doing anything.

Comment: @muru, I agree `sudo` works but it's better to eliminate the "error" message even if it is just a "warning" so I think the edit to `/etc/hosts` has to happen first. If we are interactive then yes the user can open a new terminal but if we are in a script I think it's better to get the 3rd change immediately so I suggested `export HOSTNAME=xxx`.

Comment: @H2ONaCl I only ever use a script for this, I haven't had any problems. Especially the shell variable - I don't think any external command cares for that. I always use the `hostname` command.

Comment: @muru, yes, I should have said that *my* script depends upon $HOSTNAME so I need to do `export HOSTNAME=xxx`. Even if your script doesn't need it the most complete answer might need something like this to be generally applicable. I don't know if there is a better way so I did it this way.

Comment: @H2ONaCl ah, but the HOSTNAME variablle isn't standard - IIRC dash and ksh don't  have it, zsh uses HOST, so as far as shell variables go, it's the bottom of the heap.

Comment: thank you, this was the solution for me. top voted answer didn't work on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Comment: Still works in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: If you run mDNS (the default is on for many Linux): `sudo service avahi-daemon restart`. The default hostname on Raspbian is `raspberrypi.local` and if you have more than one such device, renaming is a common task.

Answer (score 66):

## Without Restart

Changing the hostname or computer name in ubuntu **without restart**

Edit `/etc/hostname` and change to the new value,

```
nano /etc/hostname
```

Edit `/etc/hosts` and change the old 127.0.1.1 line to your new hostname

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu.local    ubuntu   # change to your new hostname/fqdn
```

**Note** : i have read it on a forum > Edit `/etc/hosts` and change the old 127.0.1.1 line to your new hostname (if you don't do this, you wont be able to use `sudo` anymore. If you have already done it, press ESC on the grub menu, choose recovery, and edit your host file to the correct settings)

Now after a reboot, your hostname will be the new one you chose

## Without Reboot

To change **without a reboot**, you can just use hostname.sh after you edit `/etc/hostname`. You must keep both your host names in `/etc/hosts` (127.0.0.1 newhost oldhost) until you execute the command below:

```
sudo service hostname start
```

**Note** : Above command to make the change active. The hostname saved in this file (`/etc/hostname`) will be preserved on system reboot (and will be set using the same service).

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10, the last part doesn't work with the following error message `sudo: unable to resolve host old-hostname`. For that part, @jesperado solution works well.

Comment: If you don't update `/etc/hosts`, mant things start to fail on 12.04.2 LTS, including the `w` command, Apache, `/sbin/reboot` and much more. **Make sure to update `/etc/hosts`**

Comment: You refer to both `127.0.0.1` for `localhost` and `127.0.1.1` for a custom hostname. Right? Then, towards the end of your answer, for an action *without a rebot*, you reference `/etc/hosts` and `127.0.0.1 newhost oldhost`. So, there is no need for a `127.0.1.1` address?

Comment: didn't work for me. i had to use `sudo nano /etc/hosts` for the change to take effect; without sudo, just `nano /etc/hosts` didn't save the change

Comment: What's the difference between restart and reboot ?

Comment: @storm I suppose he was referring to service restart

Comment: I love how this answer says "Without restart" then in that same section he says "Now AFTER A REBOOT, your hostname will be the new one you chose", nice ... but that's just what he/us try to avoid to restart/reboot :)

Answer (score 44):

The default name was set when you were installing Ubuntu. You can easily change it to whatever you want in both Desktop & Server by editing the hosts and hostname files. Below is how:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> on keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the below command: `sudo hostname NEW_NAME_HERE`

This will change the hostname until next reboot. The change won’t be visible immediately in your current terminal. Start a new terminal to see the new hostname.

2. To change the name permanently, run command to edit the host files:

   `sudo -H gedit /etc/hostname` and `sudo -H gedit /etc/hosts`

For Ubuntu server without a GUI, run `sudo vi /etc/hostname` and `sudo vi /etc/hosts` and edit them one by one.
In both files, change the name to what you want and save them.

Finally, restart your computer to apply the changes.

Answer (score 20):

## Cloud-init (Ubuntu 18+) hostname persistence

Whilst the above approaches (`hostnamectl`, `etc/hostname`, etc) work for immediate hostname change, with the advent of [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) - which can control setting of the hostname - amongst many other things. So it won't stick after a reboot if cloud-init is installed. If you want the change to stay after a reboot then you'll need to edit the [cloud-init config files](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), disable cloud-init's [hostname set/update module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#update-hostname):

```
sudo sed 's/preserve_hostname: false/preserve_hostname: true/' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
```

or disable cloud-init entirely:

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

Comment: Please upvote this answer. This worked great for me. Other answers don't work with the adoption of cloud-init.

Comment: @nslntmnx does it come installed by default on 18.04 desktop, only only server? Desktop does not have `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`. What is the package name? Just `cloud-init`?

Comment: Also, is there any way to change hostname with cloud-init instead of just disabling its override?

Comment: Yes you can change many settings using cloud-init - see the docs link in my answer - here's a link to setting the hostname: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#set-hostname

Comment: If you do not want to disable it, but want hostname changed: `sudo cloud-init clean && sudo nano /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud*/user-data` (update "hostname:") -- reboot.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a script that changes the hostname in the prescribed way. It ensures that not only `sudo` but also X11 applications continue to function with no restart required.

Usage: `sudo ./change_hostname.sh new-hostname`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
NEW_HOSTNAME=$1
echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
sed -i 's/127.0.1.1.*/127.0.1.1\t'"$NEW_HOSTNAME"'/g' /etc/hosts
echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
service hostname start
su $SUDO_USER -c "xauth add $(xauth list | sed 's/^.*\//'"$NEW_HOSTNAME"'\//g' | awk 'NR==1 {sub($1,"\"&\""); print}')"
```

Comment: What does the last line in script `su $SUDO_USER -c "xauth add $(xauth list | sed 's/^.*\//'"$NEW_HOSTNAME"'\//g' | awk 'NR==1 {sub($1,"\"&\""); print}')"` do?  Just curious.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: it takes a valid X11 authentication token (`xauth list`) and replaces the old hostname with the new hostname (`sed`). Then `awk` puts quotes around the first argument to `xauth add` because `xauth`'s input and output format are not symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had always rebooted for the changes to take effect. +1

Comment: @trakz: Actually 127.a.b.c whatever the number, is all localhost as per IETF RFC.  (most people just don't know this, but as most don't, edit approved)

Answer (score 15):

Without restart:

1. change hostname in `/etc/hostname`
2. update `/etc/hosts` accordingly
3. `sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=mynew.local.host`

Check your current hostname with `hostname -f`

Comment: With 16.04, sysctl `sudo: unable to resolve host oldname`, `sysctl: setting key "kernel.hostname": Read-only file system`. Maybe because is a CT inside Proxmox.

Answer (score 7):

To get your current hostname:

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

This can be changed in any text editor. You would also need to update entry other than localhost against 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Or just run the command "hostname" from the command line.

Answer (score 6):

The classical answer to the original poster's question is that, once you've edited `/etc/hostname`, you make it apply without restart by running [hostname(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/hostname.1.html) with the `-F` (`--file`) option as root:

```
sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

The [hostname(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/hostname.5.html) handling with `/etc/hostname` and the said program has been the same in Debian and its derivatives for over twenty years now, and [the package providing it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/hostname) has been tagged [essential](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#essential-packages) and [required](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#priorities), and IIRC the init scripts have literally used the same thing for decades (`/etc/init/hostname.conf` still contains it), so I have to say I am genuinely puzzled how nobody had mentioned this already :)

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Comment: @nslntmnx erm, what? What new dependency did Ubuntu 18 introduce to pull in cloud-init by default? You may be thinking of some cloud-tailored images, in which case it's should not come as a surprise that they run custom cloud provisioning tools.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu 16.04

Solution based on [answer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-change-hostname-or-fqdn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lemp-droplet#answer_20926) from the DigitalOcean Comunity.

Edit *hosts* file.

`$ sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Replace *oldname* with new one.

`127.0.0.1  localhost newname`

Setup new hostname.

`$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname newname`

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 4):

1. Replace the contents of `/etc/hostname` with the desired hostname (you can edit with `sudo nano /etc/hostname`)
2. In `/etc/hosts`, replace the entry next to 127.0.**1**.1 with the desired hostname (you can edit with `sudo nano /etc/hosts`)
3. Execute `sudo service hostname restart; sudo service networking restart`

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Comment: @nslntmnx are you sure about this? I see in the cloud-config.txt 
`# if you do nothing you'll end up with:
#  * /etc/hostname (and 'hostname') managed via: 'preserve_hostame: false'
#    if you do not change /etc/hostname, it will be updated with the cloud
#    provided hostname on each boot.  If you make a change, then manual
#    maintenance takes over, and cloud-init will not modify it.`
I currently don't have Ubuntu 18 so I cannot test it until the weekend.

Answer (score 4):

## Ubuntu 16.04

This is without **restart** and without any terminal use.

- Go to **System Settings -> Details**.
- There it is. Beside **Device name**, there is a text-box.
- Edit text-box and close window.

Open terminal. See for yourselves.

(For older versions, the text-box is not editable.)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo hostname your-new-name
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

That should do the job I think

Comment: I don't think this will survive a restart

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Answer (score 3):

I have read the answers, But I think Probably you are looking for this:

Just execute these two commands after editing the `/etc/hostname` file.

```
$ sudo service hostname restart
$ exec bash
```

That's all. No need to restart.Also make sure you also change the name in `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Unlike many other answers, this doesn't update `/etc/hosts` (I confirmed on 14.04).

Comment: Warning: won't work with Ubuntu 18+ which is running cloud-init by default, which controls hostname on boot.

Comment: while this does work, it should be noted it only applies to the current terminal window and not the overall X session