# How do I get the new hostname into syslog after changing the hostname?

Tags: system, hostname

When I installed Ubuntu I named my computer "test"

after the installation was finished, I renamed the hostname to somewhat nicer:

```
sudo hostname silversurfer
```

And I added the hostname to `/etc/hosts`

But still **even after a reboot**, in syslog all messages are preceeded by "test":

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
Feb 24 04:51:28 test ntpd[4598]: peers refreshed
Feb 24 04:51:28 test ntpd[4598]: Listening on routing socket on fd #24 for interface updates
...
```

My `/etc/hosts/` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   test silversurfer

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart)

Comment: it is not a duplicate, I did exactly what that answer suggests, but my syslog still has the old host in it. Even after several reboots!

Comment: Did you restart networking?

Comment: sure, I rebooted! that will restart everything won't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out:

the first hostname for 127.0.1.1 in `/etc/hosts` is mentioned in syslog, so you have to change:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   silversurfer test

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the hostname Permanently
Edit the file **/etc/hosts**

```
# vi /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.1.100    sambafileserver    samba
```

Setting up Hostname in /etc/hostname file

```
# echo "Your Hostname Herer" > /etc/hostname
# hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

**Example:**

```
# echo "sambafileserver" > /etc/hostname
# hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

Then **Restart** the Desktop or Server.

Logs file which Created Before hostname change will be in test.