# How to change the name of localhost to custom name which is available to other users in lan

Tags: 14.04, hostname

I need to use the custom url name which is able to access from all devices in LAN.

I know that it can be changed from the /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   myname
127.0.1.1   system09-System-Product-Name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

While entering the myname hosts it is available to access myname/urlpath .

It is accessible only for my system.

How can i make this available to access from other system in LAN too ?

Update :

```
127.0.0.1   allau
192.168.1.16    sul
127.0.1.1   system09-System-Product-Name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add :

```
Your Network Ip address          Name you want
```

**Example :**

```
192.168.0.1      My_Pc
```

`127.0.0.1 & 127.0.1.1` are loop-back Ip addresses .

To know your Ip address just type `ifconfig` in **Terminal** .

More help [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart)

Comment: 192.168.1.16 sul - I updated in the host file but it is accessible to access sul/folder from my name system but not from another system which is in lan. Should i restart the system ?

Comment: post the output of host file

Comment: I have updated the output of host in my question

Comment: reboot and try again

Comment: you should add the same in other pcs , if you dont have dns server