# How to create and configure DNS Server in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server

Tags: networking, server, dns

[How to change the name of localhost to custom name which is available to other users in lan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465638/how-to-change-the-name-of-localhost-to-custom-name-which-is-available-to-other-u)

As the extension of my previous question i want to know how to implement DNS Server and configure it.

In simple words :

All computers that are connected in LAN should be able to access in the below way

My Computer's ip is `192.168.1.6/myapp`

It should be accessed from all computers by `server/myapp` . How can i do this ?

Note :

I don't want to make change in the hosts file like in the above mentioned questin. I want to make it accessible from all computers.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname

Answer (score -1):

see the bellow post.
I think it helps:

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/dns.html

Comment: Pointing to the server guide is not a bad thing in itself  - only point to the current version.