# How do you make sure that new hostname is successfully broadcast to the network?

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager

I am trying to reset my hostname, but I am not sure if the broadcast is successful or not, is there a way to check?

```
user:~$ sudo hostname newhostname
user:~$ sudo dhclient
sudo: unable to resolve host newhostname

user:~$ sudo dhclient
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Is `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` an indication of successful broadcast?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need to change `/etc/hosts` to reflect that change.

Look at [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/q/87665/350004)